# 1 Plot, 2 Scale/Axis

Tags: plotting, customization

[image]

I would like to plot those two datasets on top of each other. But they have very different range on the $y$ axis. How can I have two different axis?

I found the following on the help menu but quite esoteric for me and I can`t adapt it to data (vs. function):

```
TwoAxisPlot[{f_, g_}, {x_, x1_, x2_}] := 
 Module[{fgraph, ggraph, frange, grange, fticks, 
   gticks}, {fgraph, ggraph} = 
   MapIndexed[
Plot[#, {x, x1, x2}, Axes -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][#2[[1]]]] &, {f, g}]; {frange, 
grange} = (PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange])[[
  2]] & /@ {fgraph, ggraph}; fticks = N@FindDivisions[frange, 5]; 
 gticks = Quiet@
Transpose@{fticks, 
  ToString[NumberForm[#, 2], StandardForm] & /@ 
   Rescale[fticks, frange, grange]}; 
Show[fgraph, 
 ggraph /. 
Graphics[graph_, s___] :> 
 Graphics[
  GeometricTransformation[graph, 
   RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, grange}, {{0, 1}, frange}]], s], 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{fticks, gticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]]
```

Comment: You'll find a lot of info with this search: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/TwoAxisListPlot

Comment: @Szabolcs, Thank You I found the above bouncing from your link !

Comment: You can start by replacing the appropriate line: `{fgraph, ggraph} = MapIndexed[ListPlot[#, Axes -> True, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][#2[[1]]]] &, {f, g}];`.

Comment: Ooh, this is an ancient one, I remember implementing my own version some 5 years before.

Comment: Come on, am I the only one who finds "2 scales, 1 plot" hilarious?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

This can be done with `Overlay` if the `ImagePadding` and the horizontal range for each plot is the same. For example,

```
plot1 = ListLinePlot[
    Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100}]],
    PlotStyle -> Blue,
    ImagePadding -> 25,
    Frame -> {True, True, True, False},
    FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Blue, Automatic, Automatic}
]
```

[image: Plot 1]

```
plot2 = ListLinePlot[
    Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 100}, {100}]],
    PlotStyle -> Red,
    ImagePadding -> 25,
    Axes -> False,
    Frame -> {False, False, False, True},
    FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}},
    FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Red}
]
```

[image: Plot 2]

```
Overlay[{plot1, plot2}]
```

[image: Double-axis plot]

Edit: Cleared up which axis is which using `FrameStyle`.

Comment: Note that [previous versions of posts are available](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/629/revisions) and there's a box where you can put a note about the changes.  It's not necessary to put the note directly into the post.

Comment: BTW +1 for using `Overlay` :-)  I never managed to make good use of it.

Comment: How about having both vertical axes on the same side? This would allow for three or more vertical axes...

Comment: @P.Fonseca I guess you could do it if you specified the ticks in an interleaved fashion. But I wouldn't want to read a plot like that, would you? I prefer to stack up plots with a single pair of axes.

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens, Thank You very much. I will leave it open to see if some other experts come up with alternative but this definitely solved my problem !

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens in my field, there are a lot of graphics organized like in the following schematics: http://i.imgur.com/h13bH.jpg.

Comment: Setting `PlotRange -> All` or `PlotRange -> Full` breaks the numbering on the right-hand axis. Any idea why, and how to fix it?

Comment: @poorsod, I suggest you post a new question with an example showing your problem.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson In V10 it works with `PlotRange -> All` and `FrameTicks -> All`

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson using `FrameTicks -> All` instead of the proposed solution solved it for me.

Comment: @eldo has posted a nice solution using `Overlay` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100456/37757) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103075/37757).

Comment: Nice solution. Minor update. Version 11 requires all the frame specifiers to be {{left, right},{top, bottom}} form for this to work. Using old form as shown leads to no axis scale on right.

Comment: Thanks @ArgentoSapiens .  It was the `ImagePadding` function that I didn't know about, so you can imagine the machinations I was going through trying to get overlays to line up!

Answer (score 37):

As I said, it's pretty easy to adapt the `TwoAxisPlot[]` function given in the OP. I'll give two flavors here, named `TwoAxisListPlot[]` and `TwoAxisListLinePlot[]`:

```
TwoAxisListPlot[{f_, g_}] := 
 Module[{fgraph, ggraph, frange, grange, fticks, 
   gticks}, {fgraph, ggraph} = 
   MapIndexed[
    ListPlot[#, Axes -> True, 
      PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][#2[[1]]]] &, {f, g}]; {frange, 
    grange} = 
   Last[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange]] & /@ {fgraph, 
     ggraph}; 
  fticks = Last[
     Ticks /. 
      AbsoluteOptions[fgraph, 
       Ticks]] /. _RGBColor | _GrayLevel | _Hue :> ColorData[1][1];
  gticks = (MapAt[Function[r, Rescale[r, grange, frange]], #, {1}] & /@
       Last[Ticks /. 
        AbsoluteOptions[ggraph, 
         Ticks]]) /. _RGBColor | _GrayLevel | _Hue -> 
     ColorData[1][2];
  Show[fgraph, 
   ggraph /. 
    Graphics[graph_, s___] :> 
     Graphics[
      GeometricTransformation[graph, 
       RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, grange}, {{0, 1}, frange}]], s], 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Transparent}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{fticks, gticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]]

TwoAxisListLinePlot[{f_, g_}] := 
 Module[{fgraph, ggraph, frange, grange, fticks, 
   gticks}, {fgraph, ggraph} = 
   MapIndexed[
    ListLinePlot[#, Axes -> True, 
      PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][#2[[1]]]] &, {f, g}]; {frange, 
    grange} = 
   Last[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange]] & /@ {fgraph, 
     ggraph}; 
  fticks = Last[
     Ticks /. 
      AbsoluteOptions[fgraph, 
       Ticks]] /. _RGBColor | _GrayLevel | _Hue :> ColorData[1][1];
  gticks = (MapAt[Function[r, Rescale[r, grange, frange]], #, {1}] & /@
       Last[Ticks /. 
        AbsoluteOptions[ggraph, 
         Ticks]]) /. _RGBColor | _GrayLevel | _Hue -> 
     ColorData[1][2];
  Show[fgraph, 
   ggraph /. 
    Graphics[graph_, s___] :> 
     Graphics[
      GeometricTransformation[graph, 
       RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, grange}, {{0, 1}, frange}]], s], 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Transparent}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{fticks, gticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]]
```

Test:

```
d1 = Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100}]];
d2 = Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 50}, {100}]];
GraphicsGrid[{{ListLinePlot[d1], ListPlot[d2]},
             {TwoAxisListPlot[{d1, d2}], TwoAxisListLinePlot[{d1, d2}]}}]
```

[image: two-axis plots]

Comment: If anybody's interested, I could modify the functions a bit to take options (e.g. nondefault colors for the two plots)...

Comment: I would definitely be interested to add options I like to customize my plot a lot. Would it be possible for the function to take all the ListPlot option. Many thanks for your answer and attention.

Comment: That would take a fair bit of effort. Would you mind a wait of a few days?

Comment: `TwoAxisListPlot` does not work on version 7, but `TwoAxisListLinePlot` does.  Can you tell why?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't quite know why; I don't have version seven to test it on. What exactly happens?

Comment: I see this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp1Iw.png

Comment: @J.M., Thanks for the Edit !

Comment: I still need to work on the version that allows for picking custom colors, @500, but that will take some more time, as I have other things to do...

Comment: @Öskå, yes, I really should be looking into that, but I've been somewhat busy lately. I do promise to work on this in the near future.

Comment: Is it possible to pass the range for each of the axis to the function?

Comment: did the more customizable version of this ever get finished? I'm looking for custom colors etc

Comment: @Beau, no, I haven't yet found the time; maybe someday...

Answer (score 29):

Even though this question has been flagged as answered, I think the answers are more complicated than they need to be (with respect to the authors).  I offer the following, which takes advantage of FrameTics:

```
(*create 2 lists*)
x1 = Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]];
x2 = 25 Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]];

(*set nice plot options*)
SetOptions[ListPlot, ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Blue}}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-50, 50}}, 
FrameLabel -> {"Progress", "Red Line","Descriptive Title", "Blue line"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {12, FontFamily -> "Arial"}];

(*display, using FrameTicks for the bottom axis to show what it does*)
ListPlot[{x1, x2},FrameTicks -> {{{0, "Beginning"}, {25, "Early"},
{50, "Middle"},{75,"Almost\nFinished"}, {100, "Finished"}}, Automatic, None,Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As expected, x2 goes off ListPlot's range and needs a different scale. This can be accomplished by rescaleing x2 and using FrameTics to create a rescaled axis on the right. First, rescale x2 using the function rescaled[]:

```
datamax = Max[x2]; datamin = Min[x2];
datarange = datamax - datamin;
plotrange = 100; plotmin = -50;
rescaled[x_] := (x - datamin) plotrange/datarange + plotmin
```

Next, create new axis lables for the right axis::

```
axeslabel[v_] := {rescaled[v], ToString[v]}
rightaxis = Table[axeslabel[v], {v, -500, 500, 100}]
```

Finally, create the new ListPlot:

```
lp = ListPlot[{x1, x3},FrameTicks -> {{{0, "Beginning"}, {25, "Early"}, {50, 
  "Middle"}, {75, "Almost\nFinished"}, {100, "Finished"}}, Automatic, None, rightaxis}]
x3 = rescaled[#] & /@ x2;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See how easy that was!

Upon reflection my approach isn't too different from Peter Breitfeld's, except perhaps that I made a more general rescaling routine.

Comment: Thank you George. Which version of MMA that you used?

Comment: I guess that it was the most current vs at the time.  It was five years ago, and we have one release a year, so probably version 5.  Did you try to do this with a more recent version, but it didn't work?

Answer (score 27):

Hope is the last to die. Nine years later, we finally have a native multi-axis implementation.

```
ListLinePlot[
    {PrimePi[Range[100]], EulerPhi[Range[100]]}
    ,MultiaxisArrangement -> All
]
```

Here is the [link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultiaxisArrangement.html) to the official documentation.

[image]

Comment: Nice. Does anybody know why this is limited to `ListPlot` and not included to `Plot` and family members?

Comment: many of the plot options are not available with this solution unfortunately. for example you cannot specify the plot range.

Answer (score 19):

**Most compatible solution:**

The solutions provided are not compatible with plots that contain labels. Here's a solution with possibility to add options:

```
TwoAxisListPlot[{f_, g_}, opts___] := 
 Module[{fgraph, ggraph, frange, grange, fticks, 
   gticks}, {fgraph, ggraph} = 
   MapIndexed[
    ListPlot[#, Axes -> True, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][#2[[1]]], 
      opts] &, {f, g}]; {frange, 
    grange} = (PlotRange /. 
        AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange])[[2]] & /@ {fgraph, ggraph}; 
  fticks = N@FindDivisions[frange, 5];
  gticks = 
   Quiet@Transpose@{fticks, 
      ToString[NumberForm[#, 2], StandardForm] & /@ 
       Rescale[fticks, frange, grange]};
  Show[fgraph, 
   ggraph /. 
    Graphics[graph_, s___] :> 
     Graphics[
      GeometricTransformation[graph, 
       RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, grange}, {{0, 1}, frange}]], s], 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{fticks, gticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]]
```

And here's how it's called:

```
TwoAxisListPlot[{Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100}]], 
  Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100}]]}, {Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> "Hello there!", PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Small}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"Mean magnetic field (T)", 
     "(Hz)"}, {"Some parameter", ""}}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution,  however the scaling appears to have gone wrong, I notice the y-axis plots I was conducting were not aligning perfectly with the y-axis, it was slightly out. Please can you check and fix.

Comment: @SPIL sorry man. I haven't worked on Mathematica in a while.

Comment: Have you switched to using R instead then?

Comment: @SPIL I used to be in science/academia. Now I'm a professional software developer. I don't need Mathematica anymore because I used to use it for data analysis.

Comment: @The Quantum Physicist, I'm testing this in V12, the `PlotRange -> All` is working well, but if I want to specify the PlotRange values for both two verticle axes, it doesn't seem to let me. Is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 15):

If you want to use David Park's [Presentations](http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/) package, you can reset the ticks and it will look like this:

```
data1 = {{1, 1.1}, {2, 1.5}, {3, 0.9}, {4, 2.3}, {5, 1.1}};
data2 = {{1, 1001.1}, {2, 1001.5}, {3, 1000.9}, {4, 1002.3}, {5, 1001.1}};

<<Presentations`
crop[x_] := (x - 1000)
Draw2D[
 {
  {Red, Thickness[0.02], Opacity[0.3], 
   ListDraw[data1, Joined -> True]},
  Blue, ListDraw[{#1, crop[#2]} & @@@ data2, Joined -> True]
  },
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic,
      CustomTicks[crop, {1001, 1002.2, 0.2, 5},
         CTNumberFunction -> (Style[#, FontColor -> Blue] &)]},
   {Automatic, Automatic}},
 PlotLabel -> Row[{Style["data1", Red], ", ", Style["data2", Blue]}],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 15):

Here is just a quick update of J.M.'s code to use some newer (read *undocumented*) functions in the `` Charting` ``context.

```
TwoAxisListPlot[{list1_, list2_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{plot1, plot2, ranges},
  {plot1, plot2} = ListLinePlot /@ {list1, list2};
  ranges = Last@Charting`get2DPlotRange@# & /@ {plot1, plot2};
  ListPlot[
   {list1, Rescale[list2, Last@ranges, First@ranges]},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
      Charting`FindTicks[First@ranges, Last@ranges]}, {Automatic, 
      Automatic}},
   FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, ColorData[97][2]}, {Automatic, 
      Automatic}},
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListPlot]]
   ]
  ]

d1 = Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100}]];
d2 = Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 50}, {100}]];
GraphicsGrid[{{ListLinePlot[d1], 
   ListPlot[d2]}, {TwoAxisListPlot[{d1, d2}], 
   TwoAxisListPlot[{d1, d2}, Joined -> True]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Superb! This should be a Mathematica builtin function!

Comment: @grbl - Thanks! You should take a second and send them a message, http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/ , even linking here if you like.  The more users who request a feature, the more likely it will be hooked up.

Comment: It's been requested by many users since the 90s

Answer (score 14):

Using [`ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots), you can combine arbitrary plots into two-axes plots, without the need to create a new version for every type of plot:

```
ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][
 ListLinePlot[
  Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100}]],
  PlotStyle -> Blue, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Blue
  ],
 Plot[
  x^2, {x, 10, 100},
  PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Red
  ],
 "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"
 ]
```

[image]

Note that the frame styles of the two plots where automatically applied to the appropriate axes, and that it is easy to combine `Plot` together with `ListPlot`. (`CombinePlots` also works with different `ScalingFunctions` etc, see the documentation for more details & examples)

Comment: Thanks! This works seamlessly with DateListPlot[].  I can even use the PlotLegends option in each subplot and then the combined plot has the correct legend.

Answer (score 13):

I needed a easy to modify "TwoAxisDateListPlot".

Thanks ArgentoSapiens for the inspiration. 
Here is my version.

```
list1 = FinancialData["GE", "Feb. 5, 2014"];
list2 = FinancialData["Gold", "March. 5, 2014"];
TwoAxisDateListPlot3[list1, list2, AspectRatio -> 0.3, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[TwoAxisDateListPlot3]
Needs["Calendar`"];
TwoAxisDateListPlot3[dat1__, dat2__, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Block[
{data1 = dat1, data2 = dat2, plot1, plot2, userOptions,defaultOptions, minx, maxx, temp},
(* display two datelist-graphs on one diagram *)

(* span x *)
If[DateQ[data1[[1, 1]]] (* find out date format *),
temp = SortBy[data1[[;; , 1]]~Join~data2[[;; , 1]], AbsoluteTime];
minx = temp[[1]]; maxx = temp[[-1]],
minx = Min[{data1[[;; , 1]], data2[[;; , 1]]}]; 
maxx = Max[{data1[[;; , 1]], data2[[;; , 1]]}]
];

(* get options *)
userOptions = FilterRules[{opts}, Options[DateListPlot]];
defaultOptions = FilterRules[{PlotRange -> {{minx, maxx}, {All, All}}, 
ImagePadding -> {{40, 40}, {25, 5}}}, Options[DateListPlot]];

(* do the plots *)
plot1 = DateListPlot[data1, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}},
  FrameStyle -> {Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold], 
  Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, Blue], Automatic, 
  Automatic}, userOptions, defaultOptions] // Quiet;
plot2 = DateListPlot[data2, PlotStyle -> Darker[Green], Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}},
  FrameTicks -> All,
  FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, 
    Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, Darker[Green]]}, 
  userOptions, defaultOptions] // Quiet;
Overlay[{plot1, plot2}]];
```

Comment: What is DateQ? It seems not to a buit-in.

Comment: @iav It is loaded by ``Needs["Calendar`"]``

Comment: How can make a `FrameLabel` appear if the scale of one of the axes is such that ticks like 0.0001, 0.0002, etc. are displayed (the point is that it essentially requires 5 digits plus a dot to show the scale of the axis and hence the corresponding `FrameLabel` is not visible)? The `FrameLabel` is there, when I export the plot to PDF, I can see a small part of it. I tried to play with `FrameMargin` as an option to the `Overlay` function, but that only adds white space.

Answer (score 7):

By the upper Mr. Jason B.'s nice codes on `TwoAxisListPlot`, I made one on `DateListPlot` as `TwoAxisDateListPlot` as following, some notations listed for  helping others to change it to other `***Plot` cases.

```
TwoAxisDateListPlot[{datelistLeft_?ListQ, dateListRight_?ListQ},opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
    Module[ {shapedListRight, plotLeft, plotRight, twoRanges, result},

        (*check lists' depth*)
        If[ Or[ArrayDepth@datelistLeft != 2, ArrayDepth@dateListRight != 2],
            Return[$Failed]
        ];

        (* to be reshaped*)
        shapedListRight = dateListRight;

        (*find plots'Ranges*)
        {plotLeft, plotRight} = 
         DateListPlot /@ {datelistLeft, shapedListRight};
        twoRanges = 
         Last@Charting`get2DPlotRange@# & /@ {plotLeft, plotRight};

        (*reshape dataRight*)
        shapedListRight[[;; , 2]] = 
         Rescale[shapedListRight[[;; , 2]], Last@twoRanges, First@twoRanges];

        (*draw together*)
        result = DateListPlot[{datelistLeft, shapedListRight},
          Frame -> True, 
          FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
             Charting`FindTicks[First@twoRanges, 
              Last@twoRanges]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
          FrameStyle -> {{ColorData[97][1], ColorData[97][2]}, {Automatic, 
             Automatic}}, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[DateListPlot]]];

        (*return shaped plots*)
        Return[result];
    ]
TwoAxisDateListPlot[datelistLeft_?ListQ, dateListRight_?ListQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := TwoAxisDateListPlot[{datelistLeft, dateListRight}, opts]
```

simple demos as :

```
list1 = FinancialData["NYSE:IBM", "March. 8, 2015"];
list2 = FinancialData["NASDAQ:AAPL", "March. 8, 2015"];

TwoAxisDateListPlot[list1, list2]
```

[image]

If some options given, it shows as this.

```
TwoAxisDateListPlot[list1, list2,
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", ".", "Year"},
 FrameLabel -> {{Style["IBM", Larger, Bold], 
    Style["AAPL", Larger, Bold]}, {None, None}},
 PlotLabel -> Style["Stocks Comparsion", 18, Bold]
 ]
```

[image]

If `PlotTheme` be used, a new version comes up

```
 TwoAxisDateListPlot[{datelistLeft_?ListQ, dateListRight_?ListQ}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
        Module[ {shapedListRight, plotLeft, plotRight, twoRanges, theme, colors, result},

           (*check lists' depth*)
            If[ Or[ArrayDepth@datelistLeft != 2, ArrayDepth@dateListRight != 2],
                Return[$Failed]
            ];

            (*get colors*)
            theme = Lookup[Association[opts], PlotTheme, Automatic];
            colors = 
             Most /@ PadRight[{}, {2}, 
               "DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. 
                  Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[theme, DateListPlot])];

            (* to be reshaped*)
            shapedListRight = dateListRight;

            (*find plots'Ranges*)
            {plotLeft, plotRight} = 
             DateListPlot /@ {datelistLeft, shapedListRight};
            twoRanges = 
             Last@Charting`get2DPlotRange@# & /@ {plotLeft, plotRight};

            (*reshape dataRight*)
            shapedListRight[[;; , 2]] = 
             Rescale[shapedListRight[[;; , 2]], Last@twoRanges, First@twoRanges];

            (*draw together*)
            result = DateListPlot[{datelistLeft, shapedListRight},
              Frame -> True, 
              FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
                 Charting`FindTicks[First@twoRanges, 
                  Last@twoRanges]}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
              FrameStyle -> {colors, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
              FilterRules[{opts}, Options[DateListPlot]]];

            (*return shaped plots*)
            Return[result];
        ]
    TwoAxisDateListPlot[datelistLeft_?ListQ, dateListRight_?ListQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := TwoAxisDateListPlot[{datelistLeft, dateListRight}, opts]
```

demos as

```
TwoAxisDateListPlot[list1, list2,
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", ".", "Year"},
 FrameLabel -> {{Style["IBM", Larger, Bold], 
    Style["AAPL", Larger, Bold]}, {None, None}},
 PlotLabel -> Style["Stocks Comparsion", 18, Bold],
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing"
 ]
```

[image]

or

```
TwoAxisDateListPlot[list1, list2,
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", ".", "Year"},
 FrameLabel -> {{Style["IBM", Larger, Bold], 
    Style["AAPL", Larger, Bold]}, {None, None}},
 PlotLabel -> Style["Stocks Comparsion", 18, Bold],
 PlotTheme -> "Business"
 ]
```

[image]

or

```
TwoAxisDateListPlot[list1, list2,
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", ".", "Year"},
 FrameLabel -> {{Style["IBM", Larger, Bold], 
    Style["AAPL", Larger, Bold]}, {None, None}},
 PlotLabel -> Style["Stocks Comparsion", 18, Bold],
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
 ]
```

[image]

There's always one for using.

Answer (score 3):

ArgentoSapiens's answer works well, but if the two plots don't have quite the same horizontal range, or you want to add different-sized labels to the two vertical axes, then it can be a bit tricky to line the two plots up correctly in the `Overlay`. I figured out the following trick that helped a lot with the alignment:

1. Include *both* plots' frames and labels in *each* plot.  E.g. set `Frame -> {{True, True},{True,False}}` in both plots, and add the exact same labels to both plots.  This way all the spacing will be consistent between the two plots.
2. Set each duplicated feature to be `Transparent` in one of the two plots (e.g. using `FrameStyle`).  This way the elements will still take up the right amount of space, but when you overlay them, they won't be twice as dark as they should be.

Now when you combine the two plots using `Overlay`, they should be almost perfectly lined up, and you don't need to worry about setting the `ImagePadding`. (Although you still may need to tweak the individual plots with `ImageSize`, and/or the `Overlay` with the `Alignment` option, in order to line them up perfectly.)

Also, if you do it this way then the image will be cropped correctly, whereas there will be extra white space around the sides if you set `ImagePadding` too big.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[TwoAxisDateListPlotV12]
Needs["Calendar`"];
TwoAxisDateListPlotV12[dat1__, dat2__, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Block[{data1 = dat1, data2 = dat2, plot1, plot2, userOptions, 
    defaultOptions, minx, maxx, temp},
   (*display two datelist-graphs on one diagram*)
   (*span x*)
   
   If[DateQ[First@data1["Dates"]] 
     (*find out date format*), 
     temp = SortBy[data1["Dates"]~Join~data2["Dates"], AbsoluteTime];
     minx = First@AbsoluteTime[#] & /@ temp["Dates"]; 
     maxx = Last@AbsoluteTime[#] & /@ temp["Dates"] - 1; 
     minx = Min[{AbsoluteTime[#] & /@ data1["Dates"], 
        AbsoluteTime[#] & /@ data2["Dates"]}];
     maxx = 
      Max[{AbsoluteTime[#] & /@ data1["Dates"], 
        AbsoluteTime[#] & /@ data2["Dates"]}];]
    (*get options*)
    
    userOptions = FilterRules[{opts}, Options[DateListPlot]];
   defaultOptions = 
    FilterRules[{PlotRange -> {{minx, maxx}, {All, All}}, 
      ImagePadding -> {{40, 40}, {25, 5}}}, Options[DateListPlot]];
   (*do the plots*)
   plot1 = DateListPlot[data1, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
      Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
      FrameStyle -> {Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold], 
        Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, Blue], Automatic, 
        Automatic}, userOptions, defaultOptions] // Quiet;
   plot2 = 
    DateListPlot[data2, PlotStyle -> Darker[Green], Axes -> False, 
      Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}, FrameTicks -> All, 
      FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, 
        Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, Darker[Green]]}, 
      userOptions, defaultOptions] // Quiet;
   Overlay[{plot1, plot2}]];
```

---

```
list1 = FinancialData["APPL", "Febuary 5, 2015"];
list2 = FinancialData["GOOGL", "March 5, 2015"];
TwoAxisDateListPlotV12[list1, list2, AspectRatio -> 0.3, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]