# Two x-axis with different units connected by function using CustomTicks

Tags: plotting, packages, levelscheme

I am trying to make a plot of some photoluminescence data, where wavelength is on the x-axis, and intensity is on the y-axis. Also, I would like to have the graph boxed, with the upper x-axis having units of energy in eV, connected to the wavelength through the function: energy=1240/wavelength.
I have tried to use the `TickLabelFunction` in the [LevelScheme package](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/), and have only partly succeeded. I can't control the number of decimal points for the ticks on the energy scale. For some reason, `N[]` doesn't work. 
Also, the energy tickmarks seem to follow the wavelength ticks, i.e. one energy tick for each wavelength tick. I would like those ticks to be spaced nonlinearly and independently of the other axis, e.g. having them increase with steps of 0.2 eV.
Here is a small code that I hope will illustrate my problem.

```
test = List[{500, 50}];
ListPlot[test, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 600, 
PlotRange -> {{400, 800}, {-10, 110}}, 
FrameLabel -> {"Wavelength (nm)", "Intensity (a.u.)", "Energy (eV)"},
FrameTicks -> {LinTicks[400, 800, 100, 5], LinTicks, 
LinTicks[400, 800, 100, 5, 
TickLabelFunction -> Function[x, N[1240/x, 2]]], 
StripTickLabels[LinTicks]}]
```

Any input appreciated, either using the LevelScheme package or not. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post an image with the "model"  of your desired output together with a few points to generate the plot?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Did you check [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis)? It might give you some clues.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a method to generate the ticks automatically based on the plot range.

It uses `FindDivisions` to select "pleasing" values.

```
eVticks = {1240/#, NumberForm[N@#, {2, 1}]} & /@ FindDivisions[1240/{##}, 8] &;

ListPlot[{{500, 50}},
 Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{400, 800}, {-10, 110}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Wavelength (nm)", "Intensity (a.u.)", "Energy (eV)"},
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, eVticks}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With sub-ticks as requested:

```
eVticks = Join[
    {1240/#, Null} & /@ FindDivisions[1240/{##}, 8*6],
    {1240/#, NumberForm[N@#, {2, 1}]} & /@ FindDivisions[1240/{##}, 8]
   ] &;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I like both of the solutions here. But what about minor tick marks, how would you get those in there, and get them to be non-linear?

Comment: @GOt I added a method to my answer.  I have not tested it extensively but I believe it is correct.  If you find that  irregularity in the sub-ticks occurs I'll provide another method.

Comment: Thanks so much! It seems to work perfectly.

Comment: It might be a good idea to isolate the `1240/#` stuff in a function to make the routine easier to generalize.

Comment: @Sjoerd this is merely an illustration, not a packaged solution.  There are a number of things I would add if I were making this a reusable function.

Answer (score 11):

I would define my upper ticks so that it should be easy to change the number of decimal points if needed (thanks to Mr.Wizard for pointing out a mistake).

```
upperTicks = Module[{labels, positions},
 labels = Range[1240/400, 1240/800, -0.2];
 positions = 1240/# & /@ labels;
 Transpose[{positions, labels}]];

upperTicksMinor = Module[{labels, positions, size}, 
 labels = Range[1240/350, 1240/850, -0.05];
 positions = 1240/# & /@ labels;
 labels = "" & /@ Range[Length[labels]];
 size = {0, 0.002} & /@ Range[Length[labels]];
 Transpose[{positions, labels, size}]];
```

and then use them :

```
ListPlot[test, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 600, 
 PlotRange -> {{400, 800}, {-10, 110}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Wavelength (nm)", "Intensity (a.u.)", "Energy (eV)"},
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, 
 Join[upperTicks, upperTicksMinor]}}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Your top ticks run the opposite direction from the example that the OP gave.  Also, he wrote: " I would like those ticks to be spaced nonlinearly ..."

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes I inverted the direction - will fix it. Isn't the OP asking for 0.2 eV increments though ?

Comment: When I run the OP's code I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SoFmh.png).  Note the function `1240/x`.

Comment: Looking good. +1

Comment: I like both of the solutions here. But what about minor tick marks, how would you get those in there, and get them to be non-linear?

Comment: @GOt Please see update. Have a look at `FrameTicks`, you can customize them to your liking.