# Wavelength, wavenumber, energy and frequency in a ruler

Tags: plotting, graphics, units, ticks, logarithmic-scale

I would like to generate set of four axis relating wavelength, wavenumber, energy and frequency in an arbitrary range. Like in this image  but without the labels such as "RADAR".

[image: example of ruler]

The selection of the nice numbers could be done similar to [plots with two x-axis with different units](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/two-x-axis-with-different-units-connected-by-function-using-customticks) but without an ordinate "y axis".

```
range = {Quantity[0.1, "THz"], Quantity[10, "THz"]};
ticksmeV = FindDivisions[QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity["Planck's constant"] #, "meV"] & /@ range, 10]
```

> {0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45}

and so on. But I'm not clear how to put this in a graphic with correct scaling. What would be the best way to do this both in linear and logarithmic scaling?

**Edit**

Based in the answer by @ubpdqn I have done this:

```
rangeTHz = Quantity[{0.1,10}, "THz"];
rangemeV = UnitConvert[Quantity["Planck's constant"] #, "meV"] & /@ rangeTHz;
range\[Lambda] =  N@UnitConvert[Quantity["Speed of Light"]/#, "micrometer"] & /@ rangeTHz
rangeWn = N@UnitConvert[#/Quantity["Speed of Light"], "Wavenumbers"] & /@ rangeTHz
TableForm@Table[HorizontalGauge[Null, k, GaugeFrameStyle -> Transparent,  ScalePadding -> {0, 0}, ScaleDivisions -> 10, GaugeMarkers -> None, GaugeLabels -> Placed[QuantityUnit@First@k, Top], ImageSize -> 600, GaugeFaceStyle -> Transparent, LabelStyle -> 16,  AspectRatio -> 1/15], {k, {rangeTHz, rangemeV, range\[Lambda], 
rangeWn}}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

but the problem is that the Wavelength scaling should be inverted. How can I fix that?

Comment: Never used it, but by reading the documentation maybe `ScalingFunction->"Reverse"` could do the trick? You'll have to dispose of `Table` and create the list manually, I guess.

Comment: @Peltio, it seems that `ScalingFunction->"Reverse"` have no effect on `HorizontalGauge`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [`HorizontalGauge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HorizontalGauge.html). Obviously you can format and change from static to suit your needs:

```
HorizontalGauge[36, {0, 45}, GaugeFrameStyle -> Gray, 
 ScalePadding -> {.08, .1}, ScaleDivisions -> 10, 
 GaugeMarkers -> None, GaugeLabels -> Placed["meV", Above], 
 ImageSize -> 400, GaugeFaceStyle -> LightBlue, 
 GaugeFaceElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", LabelStyle -> 16]
```

[image]