# a plot with two x-axis :one for mass in eV and the other for frequency in MHz

Tags: customization, ticks, plot-themes

I'm now confused by the problem that as I was planning to draw a plot with two x-axis :one for mass in eV and the other for frequency in MHz (Note that 1MHz=6.58×10^(-10) eV is taken here), I can't make it with the following code:

```
test2 = List[{10^(-8), 10^(20)}, {2*10^(-8), 10^(34)}]
```

```
upperTicks2 = 
  Module[{labels, positions}, 
   labels = Range[10^(-9)/6.58*10^(-10), 10^(-7)/6.58*(10^-10), 10]; 
   positions = #/(6.58*10^(-10))&/@labels; Transpose[{positions, labels}]];
```

```
ListPlot[test2, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 600, 
 PlotRange -> {{10^(-9), 10^(-7)}, {0, 10^(35)}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Intensity (a.u.)", " "}, {"Wavelength (nm)", 
    "Energy (eV)"}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, upperTicks2}}]
```

And my result is
[image]

Last but not least, my code imitates the example in this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/two-x-axis-with-different-units-connected-by-function-using-customticks).

Thank for Daniel Huber. I update my code, which I think it will not    have the first problem mentioned by Daniel Huber. And the second point mentioned will not a big deal in my care.

I will thank anyone who helped me ！

Comment: Your upperTicks2 are not in the PlotRange. Extend the y plot range to negative values to get the first point right.