# Plotting functions against the same x-axis but different y-axes?

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [1 Plot, 2 Scale/Axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis)

The title speaks for itself really. Suppose I have two functions of the same variable that I'd like to visualise on the same plot (with the same x-axis) but their units and scales are totally different. Is it possible to draw separate y-axes for them?

Further, is it possible to use, for example, a log scale for one of the functions and a linear scale for the other?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/627/5

Comment: There are lots of 'log scale' questions, too, I think?