# How to get a plot generated by ggplot2 in R ggplot returned in an output cell

Tags: plotting, rlink

I'd like to get a plot generated by `ggplot2` in Mathematica but using the [`getRPlot`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16726/how-to-get-a-plot-generated-by-r-returned-in-an-output-cell) function doesn't seem to work:

```
REvaluate["library(ggplot2)"];
Show[#, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> All] & getRPlot[
  RFunction["function(){
   qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species)
   }"]]
```

I get the following error message:

> Import::general: "Document only has 0 page(s)"

Any alternatives?

Comment: Something goes wrong in the R code and the PDF doesn't quite export right.  I can't open it with Preview.app either.  I guess that makes this an R question, not a Mathematica one ... You'll get a faster answer if you extract the plot exporting code from `getRPlot` and ask on StackOverflow about what goes wrong during exporting.  I don't know enough R to help.

Comment: Give this a try: https://github.com/ayule89/ggplot