# Plotting multiple curves with multiple axes (>2) on the same plot

Tags: plotting, time-series

I'm attempting to generate a graph that depicts mulitple time series, measured in different units (but with a common time scale) on the same graph. This is a generalization of the familiar 1-plot/scale ([1 Plot, 2 Scale/Axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis)) question.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to duplicate: http://home.trainingpeaks.com/athlete/workout/RKDN7DHUWEWZHGI6TCCMKNUSAU

By way of background, this graph was data collected by a cycling computer used by a racer in an early stage of the 2014 Tour de France. Briefly, every t seconds, the cycling computer collects and calculates a set of measurements, including speed, temperature, distance traveled, power (in watts), rpm's, elevation, location, etc., along with a time stamp. These are then overlayed onto a single plot, using one of the variables (distance or time usually) as a common x-axis, and with a y-axis reflecting the units specific to that measurement.

Doing any pair of these in Mathematica on a 2-scale plot is straightforward, but I'm stumped on how to depict more than 2 in the format shown above.

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Cheers,

Mark