# Frame labels for Overlay of two plots to look like plot with two y-axes

Tags: plotting

I have a two time differential equations system: `A[t]` and `B[t]`. (I am omitting their specific form.) I would like to display the evolution of the two variables over time in a one plot with two y-axes with a label on each axis and a legend below the x-axis After days of research I found that `Overlay` could be one solution. So my code is the following:

```
p1 = Plot[A[t] /. sol, {t, 1, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Black}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14},
Ticks -> {{}, {94, 96, 98, 100}}, ImagePadding -> 25, FrameTicks -> {None, All, None, None},
Frame -> {True, True, False, False}]

p2 = Plot[B[t] /. sol, {t, 1, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
Ticks -> {{}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}}, FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All}, ImagePadding -> 25, 
Frame -> {False, False, False, True}]

p = Overlay[{p1, p2}]

Export["p.pdf", %]
```

This produces [image]

However, after another days of research I failed to figure out how to include label for each axis, `A` for left y-axis, `B` for right y-axis, and `t` for x-axis, and a legend (for the two curves) below x-axis. I tried various combinations and various versions of `PlotLabel`, `FrameLabel`, `PlotLegend`, etc. without success. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** In 10.x the syntax for `FrameTicks` was changed. More in:

[Is there a good reason for the removal of this FrameTicks syntax?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82625/5478)

---

You just need more `ImagePadding` at the side for the `FrameLabel` to show. (Note I've changed the functions being plotted since I don't have your differential equation handy.)
You can add a legend at the bottom without worrying about adding extra `ImagePadding` because it's outside the plot. Notice that I had to create both lines in the legend. Because there is only one line in this plot, an automatic setting for `LineLegend` like `LineLegend["Expressions"]` would only have had one element.

Notice also that I've turned `Axes` off, since you are using `Frame` instead.

```
p1 = Plot[5 Sin[t] + 95, {t, 1, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
  Axes -> None, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
  Ticks -> {{}, {94, 96, 98, 100}}, 
  ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {20, 2}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {None, All, None, None}, 
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[{Black, 
      Directive[Dashed, Black]}, {"First thing", "Other thing"}], 
    Bottom], FrameLabel -> {{"First thing", None}, {"Stuff", None}}]
```

[image]

```
 p2 = Plot[5 Cos[t] + 5, {t, 1, 10}, Axes -> None,
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, Dashed]}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, Ticks -> {{}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All}, 
  ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {20, 2}}, 
  Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{None, "Thing"}, {None, None}}]
```

[image]

```
p = Overlay[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

There are some more complex examples at: [1 Plot, 2 Scale/Axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot to mention that I also want a legend below the x-axis for the two curves. Can I add this? And why do we have that extra vertical line?

Comment: @Verbeia Is it right that the option `Ticks -> {{}, {94, 96, 98, 100}} `does not function here, or I missed something?

Comment: @ Verbeia, wonderful. I really appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do the same thing, but with an even more complicated data set where the horizontal ranges weren't quite the same and the two axis labels were different sizes.  I found the following trick made it much easier to line things up between the two plots:

1. Include *both* plots' frames and labels in *each* plot.  E.g. set `Frame -> {{True, True},{True,False}}` in both plots, and add the exact same labels to both plots.  This way all the spacing will be consistent between the two plots.
2. Set each duplicated feature to be `Transparent` in one of the two plots (e.g. using `FrameStyle`).  This way the elements will still take up the right amount of space, but when you overlay them, they won't be twice as dark as they should be.

Now when you combine the two plots using `Overlay`, they should be almost perfectly lined up, and you don't need to worry about setting the `ImagePadding`. (Although you still may need to tweak the individual plots with `ImageSize`, and/or the `Overlay` with the `Alignment` option, in order to line them up perfectly. For example, note that in the example in your OP, the right-hand vertical axis is a tiny bit longer than the left-hand one, and the axes don't quite meet up at the bottom-right corner.)

Also, if you do it this way then the image will be cropped correctly, whereas there will be extra white space around the sides if you set `ImagePadding` too big.