# Is there a good reason for the removal of this FrameTicks syntax?

Tags: plotting, options, language-design

In past versions of *Mathematica* one could use a terse syntax for [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html):

**{*bottom*, *left*, *top*, *right*}**

In 10.1 this syntax is no longer recognized requiring the addition of two sets of brackets:

**{{*left*, *right*}, {*bottom*, *top*}}**

However it seems that the flat form is still supported by `Frame` and `FrameStyle`.*  As a fan of terse code I prefer the flat form and I cannot think of a good reason for its removal from `FrameTicks`.  Is this a bug?

An example rendered in 10.0:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 15},
 Frame -> {True, False, True, True}, 
 FrameTicks -> {All, None, None, None},
 FrameStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Magenta}]
```

[image]

And rendered in 10.1:

[image]

Note that the top and right frame edges have tick marks despite the `None` specification; `FrameTicks -> {All, None, None, None}` is effectively ignored.

---

* It seemed that in initial experimentation `Frame` and `FrameStyle` also did not work.  After using `PlotTheme->"Classic"` as suggested by kguler these were observed to work even without the `PlotTheme` option.  kguler seems to have observed something similar so it's possible this actually happened and I'm not just fooling myself.

Comment: it seems that frame specs inside `PlotTheme` is conflicting with the user-provided frame specs: `Plot[2 Sin[x] + x, {x, 0, 15}, 
Frame -> {True, True, False, True}, PlotTheme->"Classic"]` works as expected.

Comment: @kguler Now I am very confused; it seems like the "old" syntax is working again in all cases?  Maybe this was a localized problem?  :-p

Comment: There is closely related question somewhere.

Comment: Mr. W same here:).  First,  It didn't work without `PlotTheme->"Classic"`,  not it works with or without it. (Version 10.1.0  for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015), on Wolfram Programming Cloud)

Comment: @kguler Okay that's just plain weird.  I still seem to have one case at least that continues not to work: `FrameTicks`.  I updated my question accordingly.  Hopefully this remains stable now.

Comment: somewhat related: even terser  `Frame -> {Bottom, Top, Right}` works in V9, not in V10.1.

Comment: @kguler That works also in v7; if I've seen that before I had forgotten; a shame to learn of it just after it is obsolete!

Comment: @Kuba I couldn't find it.  Please let me know if you do.

Comment: I don't recall why it was changed, but I think there was a consistency issue. But, I may just be mis-remembering. That said, "good reason" is subjective. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have no idea if the old syntax was removed for a reason, but normal behaviour can be returned with the following workaround:

```
Unprotect[Visualization`Utilities`FrameTicksQ];
Visualization`Utilities`FrameTicksQ[{
 _?Visualization`Utilities`OptionsDump`tickListQ,
 _?Visualization`Utilities`OptionsDump`tickListQ,
 _?Visualization`Utilities`OptionsDump`tickListQ,
 _?Visualization`Utilities`OptionsDump`tickListQ
}] := True;
```

Thanks to Mr. Wizard for suggesting the more robust version.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you comment on the changing behavior I *think* I observed regarding `Frame` and `FrameStyle`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I don't recall seeing any problem with `Frame` and `FrameStyle` using the flat list syntax.

Comment: Since this form is still internally supported after modifying `FrameTicksQ` and since it seems that `Frame` and `FrameStyle` still accept it I am going to presume that this was merely removed by accident during routine maintenance and not intentionally deprecated.

Comment: In version 8.0.4 there was simpler built-in definition: ``Visualization`Utilities`FrameTicksQ[{__?Visualization`Utilities`OptionsDump`tickListQ}]:=True``.