# Is FrameTicks broken in 10.1.0?

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, documentation, ticks, version-10.1

On my system, *Mathematica* 10.1.0 under Windows, none of these [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) documentation examples work correctly:

```
(* Draw frame ticks at the specified positions with the specific labels: *)

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0 °}, {Pi, 180 °}, {2 Pi, 360 °}, {3 Pi, 
     540 °}}, {-1/2, 1/2}}]


(* Specify frame ticks with scaled lengths: *)

Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{Pi, 180 °, {.4, .05}, Red}, {2 Pi, 360 °, {.4, .05}, 
     Thick}, {3 Pi, 540 °, {.4, .05}, Directive[Red, Dashed]}}, {-1, 1}}]


(* Specify frame ticks with scaled lengths in positive and negative directions: *)

Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0 °, {.4, .05}}, {Pi, 180 °, {.4, .05}}, {2 Pi, 
     360 °, {.4, .05}}, {3 Pi, 540 °, {.4, 0.05}}}, {-1/2, 1/2}}]


(* Specify the style of each frame tick: *)

Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{Pi, 180 °, {.4, .05}, Red}, {2 Pi, 360 °, {.4, .05}, 
     Thick}, {3 Pi, 540 °, {.4, .05}, Directive[Red, Dashed]}}, {-1, 1}}]
```

All produce a pink error box with a Tooltip message

[image]

#### Is this indeed a bug or have a broken something in my configuration?

#### Does it affect other versions and platforms or only 10.1.0 under Windows?

---

Related:

- [Is there a good reason for the removal of this FrameTicks syntax?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82625/121)

Comment: All broken on 10.1 on Mac Mavericks.  All working on Win 7 on 10.0.2

Comment: @Gordon Thanks.  I guess it really is a bug then.

Comment: Yep see it on 10.1, Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Same here for my Win 7/V10.1. Was working on V9.

Comment: None of these are a problem for me using Linux v10.0.0

Comment: Something is going wrong, when there are *two y-axis ticks*.

Comment: Not a bug, but a deprecated form of the tick specification.

Comment: I would say that rcollyer has provided a convincing argumentation -- somtimes "things change" and we simple humans have to adapt and break with dear habits. ;-)  In any case I would suggest to remove the bug tag because Mathematica does behave according to its current documentation.

Comment: Now the question is, which part of the documentation is incorrect? Are the examples outdated or is the list of possible setting incomplete?

Comment: Now `{bottomAndTop, leftAndRight}` does work, except for the cases where at least one of them has two ticks.

Comment: @Karsten7. which examples are you referring to? Links please. Also, oddly, you are correct, `{bottomAndTop, leftAndRight}` does work, if neither has two ticks specified. There it interferes with the _documented_ form, so blows up.

Comment: @rcollyer I'm referring to the same examples of the documentation that Mr.Wizard copied into this question. It is the last one under *Scope►FrameTicks Positions and Labeling* and the first three examples under *Scope►FrameTicks Styling*. (Just open the `FameTicks` documentation and evaluate that notebook or use the link you provided in your answer, where btw you'll see that your solution doesn't match the output shown for that specific example, as there should be ticks on all sides.)

Comment: @Karsten7. I really should have seen that link. :P

Comment: Now, I've reported the issue with the docs.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks for the comment.  Bugs tag removed, documentation tag added.

Comment: @rcollyer Perhaps you would care to answer [this related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82625/121) which I have now linked in the question above?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not a bug, the tick specification used in the documentation is incorrect. The tick specification in these examples is

```
{bottom, left}
```

which is the short form of

```
{bottom, left, top, right}
```

which was an older tick specification that was deprecated in v7 (according to the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html)). But, it was allowed to continue to work until v10. The form you are looking for is

```
{{left, right}, {bottom, top}}
```

or

```
{{{-1/2, 1/2}, None}, {{{0, 0 °}, {Pi, 180 °}, {2 Pi, 360 °}, {3 Pi, 540 °}}, None}}
```

which works just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm this bug under Win 7 *Mathematica* 10.1.0.0.

A workaround for the moment is to specify all `FrameTicks`, e.g.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {ConstantArray[{-1/2, 1/2}, 2], 
                {#, #} &@{{0, 0 °}, {Pi, 180 °}, {2 Pi, 360 °}, {3 Pi, 540 °}}}]
```

> [image: Plot]

---

Three more workarounds that narrow down the problem

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0}, {Pi, 180}, {2 Pi, 360}, {3 Pi, 540}}, {-1/2, {0, ""}, 1/2}}]

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0}, {Pi, 180}, {2 Pi, 360}, {3 Pi, 540}}, {-1/2, 1/2, 1/2}}]


Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0}, {Pi, 180}, {2 Pi, 360}, {3 Pi, 540}}, {-1/2, 1/2}}] /. 
Visualization`Utilities`ScaleFrameTicks[l1_List, {xTicks_List, wrong_}] :> 
 Visualization`Utilities`ScaleFrameTicks[l1, {{{-(1/2), 1/2}, {-(1/2), 1/2}}, xTicks}]
```