# How to use None in FrameTicks in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

`FrameTicks` are plotted all round the frame, but I only want them on the left and bottom.

```
ListLinePlot[Prime[Range[400]*800], 
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> 
    {{{49, 4}, {97, 8}, {145, 12}, {193, 16}, {241, 20}, 
      {289, 24}, {337, 28}, {385, 32}, {433, 36}, {481, 40}},
     {{-1000000, "-1m"}, {0, "0"}, {1000000, "1m"}, 
      {2000000, "2m"}, {3000000, "3m"}}}]
```

[image]

Adding `None` breaks the plot.

```
ListLinePlot[Prime[Range[400]*800], 
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> 
    {{{{49, 4}, {97, 8}, {145, 12}, {193, 16}, {241, 20}, 
      {289, 24}, {337, 28}, {385, 32}, {433, 36}, {481, 40}}, 
     None},
     {{{-1000000, "-1m"}, {0, "0"}, {1000000, "1m"},{2000000, "2m"}, {3000000, "3m"}}, 
     None}}]
```

[image]

However, the same syntax works in `Plot`.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> 
    {{{{-1, "-1y"}, {0, "0y"}, {1, "1y"}}, None},
     {{{0, 0 °}, {Pi, 180 °}, {2 Pi, 360 °}, {3 Pi, 540 °}}, None}}]
```

[image]

Is there a way to use `None` in `ListPlot`?

I am using V10.4.

Comment: The pattern is FrameTicks->{{left, right}, {bottom, top}}.  Your example seems to be using FrameTicks->{xticks, yticks} which is fine but you can't then use the first form because Mathematica will then assume your xticks belong on the left-y axsis.

Comment: @Ymareth - Thanks, I was starting from the [deprecated form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86638/363), `{bottom, left, top, right}` and didn't notice the switch to `{{left, right}, {bottom, top}}`.

Comment: Welcome, I got similarly burnt in the past :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this form...

```
ListLinePlot[Prime[Range[400]*800], Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{{-1000000, "-1m"}, {0, "0"}, {1000000, 
      "1m"}, {2000000, "2m"}, {3000000, "3m"}}, 
    None}, {{{49, 4}, {97, 8}, {145, 12}, {193, 16}, {241, 20}, {289, 
      24}, {337, 28}, {385, 32}, {433, 36}, {481, 40}}, None}}]
```

Where I've swapped the order around and nested the two axis' ticks into lists with a None at the end.

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}]
```

**Note:** `data` is some arbitrary data you want to plot