# Overlay Plots in Mathematica 11

Tags: plotting, overlay

I'm trying to do an overlay plot in the vein of the solutiosn given in ([Frame labels for Overlay of two plots to look like plot with two y-axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65671/frame-labels-for-overlay-of-two-plots-to-look-like-plot-with-two-y-axes/65672#65672?newreg=a5be8724110941cb8cf331e39488ad54)), but with the new mathematica 11 version it seems that it is not possible to get tick labeling on the right side. Is there another way to do this now?

Specifically, using:

```
p1 = Plot[5 Sin[t] + 95, {t, 1, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
  Axes -> None, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
  Ticks -> {{}, {94, 96, 98, 100}}, 
  ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {20, 2}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {None, All, None, None}, 
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[{Black, 
      Directive[Dashed, Black]}, {"First thing", "Other thing"}], 
    Bottom], FrameLabel -> {{"First thing", None}, {"Stuff", None}}]

 p2 = Plot[5 Cos[t] + 5, {t, 1, 10}, Axes -> None,
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, Dashed]}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, Ticks -> {{}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All}, 
  ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {20, 2}}, 
  Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{None, "Thing"}, {None, None}}] 

p = Overlay[{p1, p2}]
```

no longer gives tick labeling on the right side as shown in the link.

Comment: It seems that old 4element spec for `FrameTicks` is not supported anymore. It works with `FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}` though.

Comment: p.s. notice that the code essential for that question can be reduced to `Plot[ Cos[t], {t, 1, 10}, FrameTicks -> {All, All, All, All},  Frame -> True]`, try it next time :)

Comment: The issue is with the way `FrameTicks` are specified in your code. The documentation says in the detail section that the correct form is `FrameTicks -> {{left,right},{bottom,top}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper syntax for [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) is

> {{left,right},{bottom,top}}

In previous versions you could get away with using an alternative `{bottom, left, top, right}`, (correct me if I have those in the wrong order) but no longer.

Keeping your `p1` definition,

```
p2 = Plot[5 Cos[t] + 5, {t, 1, 10}, Axes -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, Dashed]}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, Ticks -> {{}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}},
   FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, All}},
   ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {20, 2}}, 
   Frame -> {False, False, False, True},
   FrameLabel -> {{None, "Thing"}, {None, None}}];
p = Overlay[{p1, p2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks everyone, that did the trick.