# Put together two ListLinePlot with right alignment

Tags: plotting, alignment

I would like to ask for some help to figure out how can i put two ListLinePlot together with right alignment.
Here is what i tried to do:

```
absnyomplot = 
ListLinePlot[
Table[{(i - 1)*5, fnyomdel[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[fnyomdel]}], 
InterpolationOrder -> 1, Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
Frame -> {True, True, True, False}, 
FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Blue, Automatic, Automatic}, 
ImageSize -> Large, 
FrameLabel -> {"Time[min]", "Abs pressure [kPa]"}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Large]];

abshomomplot = 
ListLinePlot[
Table[{(i - 1)*5, fhomdel[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[fhomdel]}], 
InterpolationOrder -> 1, Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> Red, 
Axes -> False, Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All}, 
FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Red}, 
ImageSize -> Large, 
FrameLabel -> {{" ", "Temperature [\[Degree]C]"}, {" ", " "}}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Large]];

Overlay[{absnyomplot, abshomomplot}]
```

And the result:
[image]

So the first points of the two plots should be the on the same place on the horizontal axis.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you guys! I appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the same `ImagePadding` for both images.

See also [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis).

```
fnyomdel = Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]];
fhomdel = Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 12}, 10]];
absnyomplot = 
  ListLinePlot[
   Table[{(i - 1)*5, fnyomdel[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[fnyomdel]}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1, Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   Frame -> {True, True, True, False}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Blue, Automatic, Automatic}, 
   ImageSize -> Large, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Time[min]", "Abs pressure [kPa]"}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Large], ImagePadding -> 50];

abshomomplot = 
  ListLinePlot[
   Table[{(i - 1)*5, fhomdel[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[fhomdel]}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1, Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
   FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Red}, 
   ImageSize -> Large, 
   FrameLabel -> {{" ", "Temperature [\[Degree]C]"}, {" ", " "}}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Large], ImagePadding -> 50];

Overlay[{absnyomplot, abshomomplot}]
```

[image]

(I took the liberty of generating the data. It would be better if you didn't post code that refer to unavailable data).

Comment: I ran your exact code and I get a result where the Temperature scale is missing the number scale and the Time label is cut off half way up.  I changed the ImagePadding to '75' from '50' to get all the labels to show.  However, the Temperature scale is still missing?  Any thoughts?  I am running MMA 10.1.0 on OS X 10.10.3 ...

Comment: Okay wont happen again!

Comment: If I change the FrameTicks->{None, None, None, All} in the second ListLinePlot statement to FrameTicks->All, then the numeric Temperature scale appears on the plot

Comment: @Joseph If the `ImagePadding` is too low, it might crop the `FrameLabels` and/or the `FrameTicks`. Use a higher value and you'll see them all.

Answer (score 2):

As another option for a similar plot, you can rescale the data pretty easily and just plot them with the same plot command.

```
fnyomdel = Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]];
fhomdel = Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 12}, 10]];

ListLinePlot[
 {
  Transpose@{Range@Length@fnyomdel, fnyomdel}
  , Rescale[
   fhomdel, ({Min@#, Max@#} &@fhomdel), ({Min@#, Max@#} &@fnyomdel)]
  }
 , PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameTicks -> {Automatic
   , Automatic
   , None
   , Transpose@({Rescale[#, {Min@#, Max@#}, {Min@fnyomdel, 
          Max@fnyomdel}], #} &@Range[0, 40, 10])
   }
 , FrameStyle -> {Black, Blue, Black, Red}
 ]
```

You have to do a little more work to rescale the axis ticks on the right, but it makes some things line up better. From there you can style it however you like.

[image]