# LogLogPLot with two left&right axes

Tags: plotting

I need to do a LogLogPlot as follow.

Consider the function $m(x) = x^4$. I want to plot $m(x)$ in LogLogScale adding furthermore a vertical axis on the right which shows the value of $m(x)^2$ for any given point $(x,m(x))$ in the plane.

I want to set Frame-> True and then I thought to use FrameTicks, but I don't know what function should I give to FrameTicks.

Comment: Create two different plots (one for $m(x)$, another for $m(x)^2$ but with 0 opacity) and combine different axes as explained here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/629/35091

Comment: related: [94726](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94726), [86253](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86248/put-together-two-listlineplot-with-right-alignment/86253#86253)

Comment: I believe he wants a single plot with a second nonlinear axis.  This may be a dup but I think not of the ones @yohbs has linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
LogLogPlot[ x^2 , {x, .01, 1000}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    Table[{10^i, 10.^(2 i)}, {i, -4, 6}]}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]