# Introducing dashing to distinguish curves in a multiple curve plot

Tags: plotting, style

[To combine in 1 plot data with 2 scales](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis), I use the following solution:

```
TwoAxisPlot[{f_, g_}, {x_, x1_, x2_}] := 
 Module[{fgraph, ggraph, frange, grange, fticks, 
   gticks}, {fgraph, ggraph} = 
   MapIndexed[
    Plot[#, {x, x1, x2}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}, 
      AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
      PlotStyle -> {ColorData[1][#2[[1]]]}] &, {f, g}]; {frange, 
    grange} = (PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange])[[
      2]] & /@ {fgraph, ggraph}; fticks = N@FindDivisions[frange, 5];
  gticks = 
   Quiet@Transpose@{fticks, 
      ToString[NumberForm[#, 2], StandardForm] & /@ 
       Rescale[fticks, frange, grange]};
  Show[fgraph, 
   ggraph /. 
    Graphics[graph_, s___] :> 
     Graphics[
      GeometricTransformation[graph, 
       RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, grange}, {{0, 1}, frange}]], s], 
   Axes -> True, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"XAxis", "YAxis 1", "", "YAxis 2"}, 
   FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{fticks, gticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]]
```

E.g., `TwoAxisPlot[{{x^2, x^3}, {1/x}}, {x, 0, 1}]` yields:
[image]

Yet I have trouble customizing line style within each scale. How, for example, can I make the curve of `x^3` dashed, to distinguish it from `x^2`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You should know that upvoting good questions and answers is the way to tract attention to them. Since you're using the linked result I guess you could upvote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
att = Table[Dashing[{r, r}], {r, 0, 1, .03}]; 
TwoAxisPlot[{f_, g_}, {x_, x1_, x2_}] := 
 Module[{fgraph, ggraph, frange, grange, fticks, 
   gticks}, {fgraph, ggraph} = 
   MapIndexed[
    Plot[#, {x, x1, x2}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}, 
      AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
      PlotStyle -> Thread[{att, ColorData[1][#2[[1]]]}]] &, {f, 
     g}]; {frange, 
    grange} = (PlotRange /. 
        AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange])[[2]] & /@ {fgraph, ggraph}; 
  fticks = N@FindDivisions[frange, 5];
  gticks = 
   Quiet@Transpose@{fticks, 
      ToString[NumberForm[#, 2], StandardForm] & /@ 
       Rescale[fticks, frange, grange]};
  Show[fgraph, 
   ggraph /. 
    Graphics[graph_, s___] :> 
     Graphics[
      GeometricTransformation[graph, 
       RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, grange}, {{0, 1}, frange}]], s], 
   Axes -> True, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"XAxis", "YAxis 1", "", "YAxis 2"}, 
   FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{fticks, gticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]]

TwoAxisPlot[{{x^2, x^3, x^4}, {1/x}}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: But it was a trivial modification of your posted code. I believe you're using that code without understanding it :(

Comment: I wasn't familiar with `Thread` thanks for you help