# Simple Two-Axis Plot in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting

Is there a simple way to implement a two-axis plot in Mathematica?  On Quora.com there is a suggestion to use Show to combine two different plots with the same x-axis domain and with y-axes on opposite ends of the plots.  I can't seem to get this to work though (I get only one plot shown or the other, but not both).

From Quora.com:

https://www.quora.com/Mathematica/Is-there-a-simple-way-to-make-a-secondary-y-axis-on-a-plot

"...you can also do each plot separately, frame them instead of having axes, make sure they have the same horizontal axes, plot 1 has a left handed vertical label, plot 2 has a right-handed vertical label, and then Show[{Plot1,Plot2}]."

Comment: Seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627)?

Comment: I've seen these posts that build a new function to handle a two-axis plot but I want to know if the simple approach of combining two plots with Show[{Plot1,Plot2}] will do the job if you get the axis placement right.  I like the simplicity of the approach (because I can likely remember it) and I want to know if it works.  I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: It won't; the two plots will share one axis with `Show[]`.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Hard to fathom why Wolfram hasn't implemented this directly.