# Axis label and numerical values on right side of plot

Tags: plotting

I want to produce a plot with the vertical value tick marks and values, as well as vertical axis label, on the right side of the plot. I tried to copy the plot found in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100456/46335), but, as you can see, my version is missing two things (1) the axis label, and (2) numerical values on the frame ticks. I'm wondering whether something changed between Mathematica versions. I'm using version 11.1.1 for Mac.

How can I add numerical values and an axis label to the right side of this plot?

```
data = {1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 8};
ListLinePlot[data,
 Frame -> {True, False, False, True},
 FrameLabel -> {None, None, None, "Orange Series"}, 
 FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Orange}, 
 FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All},
 PlotRange -> {{1, Automatic}, All}, 
 PlotStyle -> Orange]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code works as expected in V9.

In version 11, `{bottom, left, top, right}` form does not work for the option settings for `Frame*`. You can use the alternative `{{left, right}, {bottom, top}}` form for the values of these options:

```
FrameLabel -> {{None,"Orange Series"},{ None, None} }
```

and

```
FrameTicks -> {{None, All},{ None, None}}
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I see that format in the documentation now that you mention it. Curiously, the documentation for FrameLabel, for example, claims to not have been updated since version 6, but clearly something changed between v9 and v11

Comment: @FalafelPita, in version 9, the `{bottom, ... , right}` form works, but afaik it is undocumented; and undocumented features sometimes disappear without notice. Thank you for the accept.