# How can I plot three data sets with ErrorBars and two different vertical axes?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot 3 data sets in an ErrorListPlot. Two of these data sets can use the same vertical axis but one has another scale and I want to show them in the same Plot with two different vertical axis.
I just found this for normal ListPlots, but not for ErrorListPlot. Can you help me?

Sincerely

Edit:
Sampledata:

```
data1 = {{{1,-40}, ErrorBar[0.5]}, {3,-42}, ErrorBar[0.5]},{5,-43}, ErrorBar[0.5]},};
data2 = {{{1,-20}, ErrorBar[0.5]}, {3,-22}, ErrorBar[0.5]},{5,-26}, ErrorBar[0.5]},};
data3 = {{{1,19}, ErrorBar[0.5]}, {3,25}, ErrorBar[0.5]},{5,30}, ErrorBar[0.5]},};
```

data1 and data2 should have the same axis, data3 the other.

I tried serveral things from  [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis) post. But nothing really helps.

Comment: Please include more details, e.g. some sample data perhaps, any code that you have tried so far, and references to the existing implementation for `ListPlot`. You should include these details by editing your original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data1 = {{{1, -40}, ErrorBar[0.5]}, {{3, -42}, ErrorBar[0.5]}, {{5, -43}, ErrorBar[0.5]}};
data2 = {{{1, -20}, ErrorBar[0.5]}, {{3, -22}, ErrorBar[0.5]}, {{5, -26}, ErrorBar[0.5]}};
data3 = {{{1, 19}, ErrorBar[0.5]}, {{3, 25}, ErrorBar[0.5]}, {{5, 30},ErrorBar[0.5]}};

Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

p1 =
  ErrorListPlot[data1,
   ImagePadding -> 45,
   Frame -> {True, True, True, False},
   FrameTicks -> {All, All, None, None},
   GridLines -> Automatic,
   ImageSize -> Large,
   PlotRange -> {{0, Automatic}, {-45, -15}},
   PlotStyle -> Red];

p2 =
  ErrorListPlot[data2,
   Axes -> False,
   ImagePadding -> 45,
   ImageSize -> Large,
   PlotRange -> {{0, Automatic}, {-45, -15}},
   PlotStyle -> Green];

p3 =
  ErrorListPlot[data3,
   Axes -> False,
   ImagePadding -> 45,
   Frame -> {False, False, False, True},
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Blue},
   FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All},
   ImageSize -> Large,
   PlotRange -> {{0, Automatic}, All},
   PlotStyle -> Blue];

Overlay[{p1, p2, p3}]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this version but I failed to add FrameLabels. Now it works.. strange. But thanks buddy!