# Overlay vs Show to combine plots?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to understand  the differences of `Overlay` and `Show` to combine two plots. A typical use case is to superpose a `ListPlot` of some data with a `Plot` of a curve to fit the data.

The following example comes from the Documentation:

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}};
line = Fit[data, {1, x}, x];
parabola = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2}, x];

datplot = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red];
fitplot = Plot[{line, parabola}, {x, 0, 5}];
```

Then I tried to `Show` them together or to `Overlay` them:

```
{Show[datplot, fitplot], Overlay[{datplot, fitplot}]}
```

[image]

In this case `Overlay` doesn't work very well. But this is resolved by setting a common `PlotRange` for both plots.

```
datplot = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle->Red, PlotRange->{{0,5},{0,5}}];
fitplot = Plot[{line,parabola}, {x,0,5}, PlotRange->{{0,5},{0,5}}];
{Show[datplot,fitplot], Overlay[{datplot,fitplot}]}
```

[image]

And this time we obtain identical results.

So my question is:

What are the differences of `Show` and `Overlay` for plots? Can I do something with `Show` that I cannot do with `Overlay`? When is one more convenient than the other (again, in the context of plot superposition)?

Comment: Overlay is not a type of graphics… unlike Show ?

Comment: I'll point out that when you say "we obtain identical results", it seems that that's not quite true. If you look at the last two plots carefully, you can see that the numbers and axes are slightly darker in the second plot than the first. This is because in the first, the two plots get one axis, whereas in the second, you are overlaying one axis on another.

Comment: @march Good point.

Comment: Your statement about rasterization is *not* true.  `Overlay` never rasterizes anything.  The point is that `Show` called on multiple `Graphics` objects will always return something with head `Graphics` that has effectively merged the primitive list and options, while `Overlay` returns a thing with head `Overlay` that merely shows the items (which need not be graphics) visually stacked.

Answer (score 21):

One important use of `Overlay` is when two plots are differently scaled but you want to show them together anyway. Here is one example:

```
C1 = RGBColor[0.368, 0.507, 0.710];
C2 = RGBColor[0.881, 0.611, 0.142];

p1 =
  ListLinePlot[
   {1, 7, 2000, 5, 4, 7, 164},
   ImagePadding -> 45,
   Frame -> {True, True, True, False},
   FrameLabel -> "Blue Series",
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, C1, Automatic, Automatic},
   FrameTicks -> {All, All, None, None},
   GridLines -> Automatic,
   PlotRange -> {{1, Automatic}, All},
   PlotStyle -> C1];

p2 =
  ListLinePlot[
   {1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 8},
   Axes -> False,
   ImagePadding -> 45,
   Frame -> {False, False, False, True},
   FrameLabel -> {None, None, None, "Orange Series"},
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, C2},
   FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All},
   PlotRange -> {{1, Automatic}, All},
   PlotStyle -> C2];

Overlay[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

Now the same with `Show`

```
Show[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

`Show` preserves the different scalings whereas `Overlay` "simply" superimposes one "image" upon the other.

Comment: +1 Thanks! This is clever use-case where `Overlay` works but `Show` doesn't.

Comment: The scale 0 to 8 of the orange series is missing on Windows 10x64, Mathematica 10.3.1

Comment: Strange, I am on 10.0

Answer (score 14):

The other answers point out important differences which I won't repeat.  But here's another one.  `Overlay` is implemented by drawing everything.  It visually stacks all of its contents.  `Show` is implemented by merging the primitive lists and options.  This introduces some important differences.

For example, if the options contradict one another in plots, then `Show` will pick the first fully resolved option.  E.g.,

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
 Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, AxesOrigin -> {\[Pi], 0}]]
```

[image]

Or, you can even add the option to `Show` to override all local options.

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
 Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, AxesOrigin -> {\[Pi], 0}], 
 AxesOrigin -> {2 \[Pi], 0}]
```

[image]

`Overlay` can do nothing more than a visual superposition.  Incidentally, since `Overlay` is doing a visual superposition, that means that it might end up double-drawing things that you don't intend to be double-drawn.  For example, imagine you have plots which have `GridLines` (for simplicity, I'll just use the same plot twice here):

```
p = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
Overlay[{p, p}]
```

[image]

Oops..what happened to those grid lines?  They got a lot darker in the `Overlay` version.  They got darker because, by default, `GridLines` are rendered as partially transparent.  This was done so that they look reasonable regardless of the choice of background color you might have chosen for the graphic.  But here, what you've done is to overdraw a transparent color on itself, thereby making a darker color.  If that description wasn't very clear, then this should help to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
Graphics[{GrayLevel[0, 0.3],
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1.2, 1.2}], Rectangle[{.8, .8}, {2, 2}]}]
```

[image]

That is exactly what's going on in the `Overlay` case.  And, furthermore, it even has subtle drawing effects on things you might not have noticed at first.  For example, antialiasing is implemented as a pixel compositing operation, effectively equivalent to using transparency.  Which means that anything in a graphic which is antialiased and multiply drawn is going to look darker around the edges.  That's why the tick labels in the `Overlay` example above look darker.  If you look carefully at the screenshot you provide in your question, you'll notice that your tick labels look darker, too.

Okay...so those are some subtle issues with overdrawing.  Let's try a non-subtle issue...plots with background colors:

```
Overlay[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Background -> LightBlue], 
  Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Background -> LightOrange]}]
```

[image]

Oops...where did the sine wave go?  Because the plots are visually stacked, the background color for the second plot completely obscures everything that was drawn as part of the first graphic.

Answer (score 7):

Following your example,

```
  pp=={Show[datplot,fitplot], Overlay[{datplot,fitplot}]};
```

I can continue to operate on `Show`, e.g. as

```
  pp[[1]] // Show[#, PlotRange -> {0, 1}] &
```

Whereas

```
  pp[[2]] // Show[#, PlotRange -> {0, 1}] &
```

returns

Overlay is not a type of graphics. >>

Comment: +1 You're right. This is an important difference. Thanks! However, if you export the graphics, `Overlay` produces unrasterized output (see my edited question).