# Plot Histogram and CDF on the Same Chart

Tags: probability-or-statistics, histograms

I have this data and plotted the histogram and CDF:

```
data = {-42.0421,-57.4408,-59.7565,-78.2942,-98.1669,-100.343,-121.699,-141.606,25.527,18.5992,10.5566,3.5326,-4.28842,-16.1812,-20.7588,-33.9497,-49.4225,57.8329,52.3047,46.7013,39.5162,33.7256,27.7452,19.8653,13.5107,6.79453,13.7434,2.97742,-11.8788,-14.7843,-28.9345,-45.3735,-46.8957,-62.636,-79.8734,61.2491,54.8034,48.3178,41.5504,34.7519,27.8635,20.3261,13.0338,5.49161,97.9839,92.6601,87.162,80.6281,75.0999,69.5717,62.6603,56.887,51.1137,47.477,39.2979,30.3815,24.1294,15.2521,3.78877,-1.35049,-13.9729,-28.0871,99.1226,92.8674,86.6122,80.4608,74.0979,67.6123,60.8487,54.3631,47.6598,141.078,135.754,130.43,124.736,119.412,113.996,107.462,101.934,96.4055}
d = EmpiricalDistribution[data];
Row[{Histogram[data, 40],DiscretePlot[CDF[d, x], {x, -150, 150, 1}]}]
```

[image]

However, I can find the right method to plot them on top of each other.

I have tried the following but the chart is weird.

```
Histogram[data, 40, "PDF",  Epilog -> First@DiscretePlot[CDF[d, x], {x, -150, 150, 1}]]
```

and

```
Show[Histogram[data, 40], DiscretePlot[CDF[d, x], {x, -150, 150, 1}]]
```

Help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

edit: The final chart that I'm looking for is something like this (in excel).

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `HistogramDistribution[]`?

Comment: Could you give an example of the kind of output you desire, even if it is from other software, or hand-drawn?

Comment: You might look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is

```
DiscretePlot[CDF[d, x], {x, -150, 150, 1}, Epilog -> 
    Inset[Histogram[data, 40, Axes -> {False, True}], Center, {0.0, 1.98}, {316, 380}]]
```

[image]

What is best is largely a matter of taste.

**Addendum**

In answer to a comment by the OP, the origin of a plot can be specified by the option, `AxesOrigin`.  Applied to the code above, it gives

```
DiscretePlot[CDF[d, x], {x, -150, 150, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {150, 0}, Epilog -> 
    Inset[Histogram[data, 40, Axes -> {False, True}], Center, {0.0, 1.98}, {316, 380}]]
```

[image]

**Second Addendum**

Placing the curve in front of the histogram is no more difficult in principle but requires some fine tuning of the `Inset` size.

```
Histogram[data, 40, Epilog -> 
    Inset[DiscretePlot[CDF[d, x], {x, -150, 150, 1}, Filling -> None, 
    Axes -> {False, True}, AxesOrigin -> {150, 0}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio - .02], 
    Center, {0.0, .47}, {312, 312}]]
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to move the middle axis (for CDF) to the right  and become thee 2nd axis in my example chart?

Comment: What if I want to bring the CDF plot in-front of the Histrogram?

Comment: @iFikr  Reverse the roles of the two plots in the code in my answer.  You will have to play with the numbers `{0.0, 1.98}, {316, 380}` a bit.

Comment: I tried to figure out the best value for that `{0.0, 1.98}, {316, 380}` value and come out with `Manipulate[Histogram[npv10v2,40,GridLines-> Automatic,
Epilog -> Inset[DiscretePlot[CDF[d,x],{x,-150,150,1},Axes->{False,True},AxesOrigin->{150,0}],Center,{0.0,0.465},{a,b}]],{{a,317.35,"a"},300,320},{{b,6.5,"b"},4.0,7}]`
. The best value for a is around 317 and for b is 6.3. However, I seems to have problem to really align them correctly (changing a will affect b parameter). Anything wrong?

Comment: btw, I'm very new to Mathematica..

Comment: It's also hard to display the full CDF scale 0-1

Comment: @iFikr  Is the third figure what you had in mind?  You are correct that adjusting sizes, etc. is tedious.

Comment: That is great. But need some time to understand.. I wish to have like a simpler answer..It is true that Mathematica learning curve is quite steep