# How do i make a barchart and listlineplot with two separate vertical axis?

Tags: graphics, charts

I tried doing it with `Overlay` but the output is not a new graphics object and boundaries of the chart are overlapping. Is there a way to do this to get a new graphics object with two vertical axis for barchart and listlineplot.

I want to have something like the following or better:
[image]

Comment: I avoid `Overlay` whenever possible, because as you say it doesn't return a `Graphics` object.  You should be able to adapt [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136419/9490) to do what you want.  You have to do these things: 1) rescale the list data so that it actually has the same range as the bar char, 2) rescale the frame ticks for the list plot so they reflect the original range, and 3) make the right-hand side FrameTicks blank on the bar chart.  Then you just use `Show` to combine them

Comment: Can you post some sample data