# Resizing Overlay (two y axes)

Tags: plotting, overlay

As suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis), the way to be able to make a plot with two y axes is with `Overlay`. However, `Overlay` does not produce a graphics object which has many complications, the most basic one is, the plot cannot be resized.
When I try to do

```
Show[Graphics[Overlay[{pl1,pl2}]]]
```

on the code from the link above, I get a nicely pink, yet empty rectangle.

So, is there any way, to make this work as I assume `Overlay` is just a very dirty way to produce to axes plots. I have read in some post that `Export` should work with `Overlay` objects but still, sometimes one just needs to play with the graphics in the GUI.

Also, is there any official Wolfram suggestion how to plot a two axes plots?

Comment: You can use Show to combine the preliminary prepared plots. The Y-axes should be normalized to the same value and the manual definition of the  corresponding `Ticks` is needed.

Answer (score 6):

```
Overlay[{plot1, plot2}]

Overlay[Show[#, ImageSize -> 500] & /@ {plot1, plot2}]
```

[image]

If `Overlay` is already created you can just do:

```
o = Overlay[{plot1, plot2}]

MapAt[Show[#, ImageSize -> 500] &, o, {1, All}]
```