# Two Axes, One plot

Tags: plotting

Consider the following data indicating temperature in degree Celcius vs time in hours:

```
SeedRandom[95];
TEMPvsTIME = {Range[100], 
    Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]]}\[Transpose];


ListPlot[TEMPvsTIME, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time (hr)", "Temp (C)"}]
```

[image]

How can I include another horizontal and vertical axis on the top and on the right, scaled **for the same data/plot** to show time in minutes and temperature in Fahrenheit respectively? Unlike [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis), I am not plotting 2 datasets and the only way that comes to my mind is to create an empty dataset and use `TwoAxisPlot`. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### `` Charting`FindTicks ``

You can also use `` Charting`FindTicks `` to get the linearly scaled ticks:

```
ListPlot[TEMPvsTIME, Joined -> True, Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic,   Charting`FindTicks[{0, 100}, {32, 212}]}, 
   {Automatic,  Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 60}]}},
 FrameLabel -> {{"Temp (C)", "Temp (F)"}, {"Time (hr)", "Time (min)"}}]
```

[image]

**Update:** If you wish to have the same positions but different labels for axes pairs (as suggested by Jose in a comment) you can do

```
cft = Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}];
ListPlot[TEMPvsTIME, Joined -> True, Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{cft,
    Replace[cft[##], {x_?NumericQ, Except[""], z___} :> {x,  32 + 9/5 x, z}, 1] &},
  {cft,  Replace[cft[##], {x_?NumericQ, Except[""], z___} :> {x, Floor[60  x], z}, 1] &}},
 FrameLabel -> {{"Temp (C)", "Temp (F)"}, {"Time (hr)",  "Time (min)"}}]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** To add `GridLines`  (thanks @JoseAntonioDiazNavas for the suggestion) and quantity units in temperature labels (as in egwene sedai's answer):

```
ListPlot[TEMPvsTIME, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Replace[cft[##], {x_?NumericQ, Except[""], z___} :> 
     {x, Quantity[x, "Celsius"], z}, 1] &, 
    Replace[cft[##], {x_?NumericQ, Except[""], z___} :>
     {x,  UnitConvert[Quantity[x, "Celsius"], "Fahrenheit"], z},  1] &}, 
   {cft, Replace[cft[##], {x_?NumericQ, Except[""], z___} :> {x, Floor[60 x], z}, 1] &}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"Temp (C)", "Temp (F)"}, {"Time (hr)",  "Time (min)"}}, 
  GridLines -> {Automatic, (DeleteCases[cft[##], {_, "", ___}][[All, 1]] &)}]
```

[image]

Comment: Although a good solution, as well as  that of @CarlWoll, I am more in favor in plotting axes in which corresponding ticks are aligned to better see how values are related.

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas, very good point. Updated with a version that changes the labels only.

Comment: Nice and useful, particularly when someone wants to add `GridLines` +1

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks) to specify the kind of ticks you want. I like using `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` to specify ticks, so the following would be my approach:

```
ListPlot[
    TEMPvsTIME,
    Joined->True,
    Frame->True,
    FrameTicks->{
        {Automatic,Charting`ScaledTicks[{5/9(#-32)&,9/5#+32&}]},
        {Automatic,Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear",{#/60&,# 60&},"Nice"]}
    },
    FrameLabel->{{"Temp (C)", "Temp (F)"},{"Time (hr)", "Time (min)"}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Can we get `ScaledTicks` documented and added to the `System` functions?

Answer (score 11):

You may use the `SciDraw` Package:

```
Needs["SciDraw`"];

SeedRandom[95];
TEMPvsTIME = {Range[100], 
    Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]]}\[Transpose];


ListPlot[TEMPvsTIME, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Temp (C)", "Temp (F)"}, {"Time (hr)", 
    "Time (min)"}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{LinTicks[0, 6, 1, 2], 
    LinTicks[0, 6, 1, 2, 
     TickLabelFunction -> (UnitConvert[Quantity[#, "Celsius"], 
         "Fahrenheit"] &)]}, {LinTicks[0, 100, 20, 2], 
    LinTicks[0, 100, 20, 2, TickLabelFunction -> (#*60 &)]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: note: Carl Woll's answer works wonderfully and does not require 3rd party packages; here you need to load the extra package, but it is better documented than Charting `ScaledTicks

Comment: seai, I did not know about SciDraw. I'll start using it. Thanks!