# Regarding TwoAxisPlot or TwoAxisListPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a function and data points; I want to plot both of them in a single graph using the aforementioned command. Can "TwoAxisPlot" take the data set of points as an argument of it? I can't find the exact thing while searching through Google.I need an workout example, that I can follow. Would you please help me ?

Comment: seen [Two Axes - One Plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/165796/125) and [1 Plot, 2 Scale/Axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/627/125)?