# Adding a second axis with different scale

Tags: plotting

Let's consider the following simple example

```
Clear["Global`*"];

S0 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Now, I want to add a second horizontal axis (at the top of the frame) in which 1 unit of the lower axis corresponds to 5.2 units in the top axis. Any ideas?

Merry Christmas to all!

Comment: You can use `FrameTicks -> {{Automatic,None},{Automatic,Table[{i,5.2*i},{i,-10,10,5}]}}`

Comment: closely related/ possible duplicate: [Two Axes, One plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/165796/125)

Comment: @kglr If possible, please post a quick answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic},
      {All, Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 5.2}][-10, 10]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! One question: why the numbers of the top axis come with a dot, e.g., 20. instead of 20 (as in the lower axis)? Is there a way to remove the dots?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z,  when we tick spec is a  ``Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 5.2}]`` that function is evaluated at automatically computed `min` and `max` for associated axis.  If we provide integer arguments to this function using  ``Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 5.2}][-10,10]`` we do get integer labels.