# How do I add the axes label to my two y-axes List Plot?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot two functions on the same plot with two different y-axes. I have used [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/629/8822) answer and the result is ok; now I need to add the axes label on both the y-axes and on the x-axis. FrameLabel won't work. How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
range = {Range[1,10],Range[1,10]};
number = {Range[1,10],Range[1,10]};

p1 = ListLogLogPlot[number, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   ImagePadding -> 25, Frame -> {True, True, True, False}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Blue, Automatic, Automatic}];
p2 = ListLogLogPlot[range, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   ImagePadding -> 25, Axes -> False, 
   Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
   FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Red}];
Overlay[{p1, p2}]
```

Comment: Show the code you already have.

Comment: Check out the `AxesLabel` option.

Comment: I played around with your code a bit and it seems it is the `Frame` option that is causing problems with the `AxesLabel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Labeled[Overlay[{p1, p2}], 
  Style[#, 16, #2, ShowStringCharacters -> False] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{{Rotate["Label1", 90 Degree], 
     Rotate["Label2", 90 Degree], "XAxis"}, {Blue, Red, Black}}], 
 {Left, Right, Bottom}]
```

[image]

Comment: @mattiav27, updated.