# Combining two plots at a common x-axis

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to combine a `Plot` and a `ListPlot` at their common x-axis.  Here's an example of what I've got so far:

```
fgraph = Plot[1 - x^2
  - 0.5654788166963185 E^(-2.25 (-0.2 + x)^2)
  - 0.5654788166963185 E^(-2.25 (0.2 + x)^2), {x, -1, 1}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}];
ggraph = ListPlot[
  {{{-0.2, 0}, {-0.2, 0.5}}, {{0.2, 0}, {0.2, 0.35}}},
  Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, All}},
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}];
GraphicsColumn[{ggraph, fgraph}, Automatic, -112]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It looks pretty close to what I want, but there are a few problems:

1. The x-axes are not on the exact same horizontal scale, so they don't line up perfectly,
2. The spacing of `-112` in `GraphicsColumn` had to be found manually and it's not quite right either, and
3. I'd like to be able to adjust the top plot's `AspectRatio` to make it around half the current height.

The solution needs to be automated since this is only an example.

Note that I need to keep the two different scales for the y-axis, since the y-axes in `fgraph` and `ggraph` are measured in different units and may be orders of magnitude different.  This problem seems similar to [1 Plot, 2 Scale/Axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis) but different since I want the same x-axis at `y==0`.

Comment: Use [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html)

`Show[ggraph, fgraph,
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon That's easy and looks OK in this example, but I need to keep the two different scales for the y-axis since the y-axes in `fgraph` and `ggraph` are measured in different units and may be orders of magnitude different.  I'll clarify my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll also use kglr's approach (in his deleted answer) of insetting the list plot into the [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot) output. The one tricky part is that the entire list plot, both plot range and image padding, gets inserted. This means that if the object has any image padding, it will be shrunk when it is placed into the [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot) output. This is what happened in kglr's deleted answer.

The trick, then, is to eliminate the image padding, and make sure that [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot) uses the same plot range, which almost works:

```
fgraph = Plot[
    1-x^2-0.5654788166963185 E^(-2.25 (-0.2+x)^2)-0.5654788166963185 E^(-2.25 (0.2+x)^2),
    {x,-1,1},
    AxesOrigin->{-1,0},
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, Automatic} (* same plot range *)
];
ggraph=ListPlot[
    {{{-0.2,0},{-0.2,0.5}},{{0.2,0},{0.2,0.35}}},
    Joined->True,
    PlotRange->{{-1,1},{0,All}},
    AxesOrigin->{1,0},
    AspectRatio -> 1/4, (* adjust aspect ratio *)
    ImagePadding->0 (* eliminate padding *)
];

Show[fgraph, Epilog -> Inset[ggraph, {1, 0}, {1, 0}, Scaled[1]]]
```

[image]

Note that the horizontal axis matches perfectly now. The main issue is that setting ImagePadding to 0 caused the list plots vertical axis to disappear. One simple remedy is to increase the plot range to include the vertical axis:

```
fgraph = Plot[
    1-x^2-0.5654788166963185 E^(-2.25 (-0.2+x)^2)-0.5654788166963185 E^(-2.25 (0.2+x)^2),
    {x,-1,1},
    AxesOrigin->{-1,0},
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1.05}, Automatic} (* same plot range *)
];
ggraph=ListPlot[
    {{{-0.2,0},{-0.2,0.5}},{{0.2,0},{0.2,0.35}}},
    Joined->True,
    PlotRange->{{-1,1.05},{0,All}},
    AxesOrigin->{1,0},
    AspectRatio -> 1/4, (* adjust aspect ratio *)
    ImagePadding->0 (* eliminate padding *)
];

Show[fgraph, Epilog -> Inset[ggraph, {1, 0}, {1, 0}, Scaled[1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to you and @kglr, that looks great!

Comment: Not to gild the lily, but would it be possible to do the same with `Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}` on `ggraph`, to put the right side's ticks and labels outside the graph?  I haven't been able to get that working.

Comment: That's harder, because frame ticks always live in ImagePadding.

Comment: This is still awesome!