# Align y-Axes in Overlay plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, output-formatting

I learned about how to plot two datasets in a single plot with two y-axes by using `Overlay` as has been done in one of the answers in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis).

Now, my datasets are not just positive but the second one also has negative y-values. As a consequence, the origins of the y-axes are now misaligned in the final plot (they are not at the same height).

**Is it possible to use this method but align the origins of the different y-axes correspondingly?**

I tried to use `AxesOrigin` but it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you for your help!

**[Edit]**

Minimal working example to illustrate my problem

```
plot1 = ListLinePlot[Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100}]], 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, ImagePadding -> 30, 
   Frame -> {True, True, True, False}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Blue, Automatic, Automatic}];
plot2 = ListLinePlot[RandomReal[{-5, 40}, {100}], PlotStyle -> Red, 
   ImagePadding -> 30, Axes -> False, 
   Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Red}];
Overlay[{plot1, plot2}]
```

[image]

Reading out the `PlotRange` might be a way.

Comment: For an user with your reputation, you should know by now to include a minimal working example that shows your code and problem. Please [edit] your question to improve it. It's never too late to get you *Informed* badge by taking the [tour] and learning about [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).

Comment: You are right. I apologise for my sloppiness. I just edited my OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but some thought for you to start. If I undetstood you correctly, you want to align "zero" ticks of both axes. If so, you need to `Show` both plots with the same vertical range, and then `Overlay` new plots.

One can get `PlotRange`s by `pr1=PlotRange[plot1]` (and similarly for plot2). You also need `PlotRangePadding` with the command `pad=Options[plot1,PlotRangePadding]`. Next you compute common `PlotRange` by smth like `cpr=MinMax[Join[pr1[[2]], pr2[[2]]]]`. Now you are ready to replot both polts with this new `cpr`: `newplot1=Show[plot1,PlotRange->cpr,PlotRangePadding->pad]` and the like for the plot2. And finally `Overlay[{newplot1,newplot2}]`.

[image]

You also may use undocumented command

```
Charting`get2DPlotRange[plot1]
```

This will give you "whole" `PlotRange` including `PlotRangePadding`. in this case in `newplot1` you should use `PlotRangePadding->None` because it is already included in plotrange.

**EDIT**

Another idea. First you get "whole" `PlotRange`. Then you need to find such range (for the left axis, e.g.), so that after rescaling its zero becomes zero on the right axis:

```
Solve[Rescale[0,{x,pr1[[2,2]]},pr2[[2]]]==0,x]
```

Now you `Show[plot1, PlotRange->{x,pr1[[2,2]]},PlotRangePadding->None]`, then `Overlay[...]`.

[image]

Comment: You correctly understood my intention. However, in the actual example the ranges of the different y-axes are quite different (different regimes in terms of magnitudes). The problem is that one then also has to rescale one of the axes I'm afraid. It is a pity that this whole task is so tedious with MMA. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Great that works perfectly well. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach based on (1) `Rescale`ing the second data set  to the range of first data set so that the two data sets are aligned at the desired point, (2) Using `` Charting`FindTicks `` to find the appropriate frame ticks for the right axis.

We need a simple helper function to find the second argument for `Rescale`:

```
ClearAll[modifiedrange]
modifiedrange[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}, z_: 0] /; z <= d := {(a d - (a - b + d) z)/(b - z), d}
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
data1 = Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100}]];
data2 = RandomReal[{-5, 40}, {100}];

ao = {0, 0};
data2b = Rescale[data2, modifiedrange[MinMax /@ {data1, data2}, ao[[2]]], MinMax @ data1]
tickF = Charting`FindTicks[MinMax@data1, modifiedrange[MinMax/@{data1, data2}, ao[[2]]]];

ListLinePlot[{data1, data2b}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> {{Blue, Red}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, tickF}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
  AxesOrigin -> ao]
```

[image]

Use `ao = {0, 10}` to align the left and right axes at `10`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!