# How to plot two axis bar chart side by side

Tags: plotting, charts

I want to plot a bar chart using the given data, I am trying to plot by given 
code but chart only slightly displaced( I want it to the side by side)

```
qq = {{a, .261, 93}, {b, .247, 136}, {c, .311, 70}, {d, .336, 80}, {e, .339, 71}, {f, .337, 60}};
q1 = qq[[All, {1, 2}]]; q2 = qq[[All, {1, 3}]]
qw1 = BarChart[q1, BarSpacing -> {0, 1}, Frame -> {Left, Bottom}, 
  ChartStyle -> Darker[Red], FrameStyle -> Darker[Red], 
   ImagePadding -> 30, ImageSize -> 500, ImageMargins -> 4];
   qw2 = BarChart[q2, BarSpacing -> {0, 2}, Frame -> {Right}, 
   FrameTicks -> All, ChartStyle -> Darker[Blue], 
    FrameStyle -> Darker[Blue], ImageMargins -> 4, ImagePadding -> 30, 
     ImageSize -> 500];
     Overlay[{qw1, qw2}]
```

[image: plot of the data]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** An alternative approach with a minor modification of the code in OP:

1. Reverse the columns in `q1`: i.e. use `q1 = qq[[All, {2, 1}]];`, and
2. Use `BarSpacing -> {0, 1}` in both charts

```
q1 = qq[[All, {2, 1}]]; q2 = qq[[All, {1, 3}]];
qw1 = BarChart[q1, BarSpacing -> {0, 1}, Frame -> {Left}, 
      ChartStyle -> Darker[Red], FrameStyle -> Darker[Red], 
      ImagePadding -> 30, ImageSize -> 500, ImageMargins -> 4];
qw2 = BarChart[q2, BarSpacing -> {0, 1}, Frame -> {Right}, 
      FrameTicks -> All, ChartStyle -> Darker[Blue], 
      FrameStyle -> Darker[Blue], ImageMargins -> 4, 
   ImagePadding -> 30, 
      ImageSize -> 500];

Overlay[{qw1, qw2}]
```

[image]

Use `BarSpacing -> {-.5, 1}` in both charts to get:

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use the function `modifiedrange` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202281/125) to rescale the second data set and use `` Charting`FindTicks `` to relabel the ticks on the right frame:

```
ClearAll[modifiedrange]
modifiedrange[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}, z_: 0] /; z <= d := {(a d - (a - b + d) z)/(b - z), d}


{data1, data2} = Transpose[qq[[All, {2, 3}]]] ;
data2b = Rescale[data2, modifiedrange[MinMax /@ {data1, data2}], MinMax @ data1];

tickF = Charting`FindTicks[MinMax@data1, modifiedrange[MinMax /@ {data1, data2}]];

BarChart[Transpose[{data1, data2b}], 
   ChartStyle -> (Darker /@ {Red, Blue}), 
   BarSpacing -> {0, 1},
   ImageSize -> 500,
   Axes -> {True, False},
   Frame -> {Left, Right}, 
   FrameStyle -> { Darker /@ {Red, Blue}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, tickF}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Use `BarSpacing -> {-.5, 1}` to get

[image]

Comment: Thanks It is working.

Comment: Can suggest me how to add BarLegend at top of the plot.

Comment: @GopalVerma, try `Legended[Overlay[{qw1, qw2}], 
 Placed[SwatchLegend[Darker /@ {Red, Blue}, {"label 1", "label 2"}, 
   LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}], Top]]`

Comment: Thank, Its work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ChartElementFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html) to manually nudge the bars over by a bit, the following for example moves them 0.5 to the right:

```
ChartElementFunction -> (Rectangle @@ Transpose[# + {0.5, 0}] &)
```

For the combining part, you can search this site for ways to overlay charts cleanly (e.g. [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis)). One way is to use the `CombinePlots` function from the [`` ForScience` ``](https://github.com/MMA-ForScience/ForScience)<sup>1</sup> paclet:

```
<<ForScience`
qq = {{a, .261, 93}, {b, .247, 136}, {c, .311, 70}, {d, .336, 
    80}, {e, .339, 71}, {f, .337, 60}};
q1 = qq[[All, {1, 2}]]; q2 = qq[[All, {1, 3}]]
qw1 = BarChart[
  q1,
  BarSpacing -> {0, 1},
  Frame -> Left,
  ChartStyle -> Darker[Red],
  FrameStyle -> Darker[Red],
  ImagePadding -> 30,
  ImageSize -> 500,
  ImageMargins -> 4
  ]
qw2 = BarChart[
  q2,
  BarSpacing -> {0, 1},
  Frame -> Left,
  ChartStyle -> Darker[Blue],
  FrameStyle -> Darker[Blue],
  ImageMargins -> 4,
  ImagePadding -> 30,
  ImageSize -> 500,
  ChartElementFunction -> (Rectangle @@ Transpose[# + {0.5, 0}] &)
  ]
CombinePlots[
 qw1, qw2,
 "AxesSides" -> "TwoY", (* move the second plot to the right axis *)
 PlotRange -> All, (* ensure that all the bars are shown *)
 Frame -> {Left, Right}
 ]
```

[image]

<sup>1</sup>You can install the current version using

```
PacletInstall["https://github.com/MMA-ForScience/ForScience/releases/download/v0.88.45/ForScience-0.88.45.paclet"]
```

Comment: @Lank, Thanks, It is working.