# Combine two plots with reversed y-axis

Tags: plotting

I need to display two y-values for a list of points. I tried doing this:

```
data=Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/cJtpDmcm","Table"];
p1=ListPlot[data[[All,1;;2]],PlotRange->{{6,10},{3,7}},ImageSize->500,PlotTheme->"Monochrome",BaseStyle->Directive["TR",FontSize->16,Black],Frame->{{True,False},{True,True}},FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {All,None}},ImagePadding ->{{60, 60}, {60,10}}];
p2=ListPlot[data[[All,3;;4]],PlotRange->{{6,10},{100,300}},PlotTheme->"Monochrome",ImageSize->500,BaseStyle->Directive["TR",FontSize->16,Black],Frame->{{False,True},{False,False}},FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}},ImagePadding ->{{60, 60}, {60,10}},FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, Red}, {Automatic, Automatic}},FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[16, "TR"],PlotStyle->Red];
Overlay[{p1,p2}]
```

Output:

[image]

It works, but I wish I could rescale the red y-values so I only need to plot one set of dots. Something like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you know that the points lie exactly like that? In that case, would it do to simply put labels manually on the y-axis to the left?

Comment: They don't lie exactly like that. Placing the labels manually won't be practical if I need to change the parameters. I was hoping for something automatic.

Comment: Take a look at [MultipleAxesListPlot](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultipleAxesListPlot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tick marks on the right can constructed with an interpolation function like this:

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/cJtpDmcm", "Table"];

ifun42 = Interpolation[data[[All, {4, 2}]], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
labels = {150, 200, 250, 300, 350};
ticks = Table[{ifun42[x],
     If[TrueQ@MemberQ[labels, x], Style[x, Red], Null]},
    {x, 100, 350, 10}] // Quiet;
```

The interpolation is from the 4th column of data to the 2nd.  Note that an interpolation order of 1 spaces the tick marks linearly between the data points, not between the tick labels.  This effect can be seen by comparing the spacing of the ticks at 160 and 170 to the spacing of the ticks at 170 and 180.  A higher order interpolation, like the default of 3, gives better results.

For the horizontal and vertical gridlines, we will just use the `Epilog` option.  But first, we construct the lines like this

```
pRange = {{6, 11}, {3, 8}};
horzLines = {Thin, Dashed, 
   Red, Line[Table[
     {pt, {pRange[[1, 2]], pt[[2]]}}, {pt, data[[All, {1, 2}]]}]],
   Blue, Line[Table[
     {{pRange[[1, 1]], pt[[2]]}, pt}, {pt, data[[All, {1, 2}]]}]]};
vertLines = {Thin, Dashed, Black, Line[Table[
      {pt, {pt[[1]], pRange[[2, 1]]}}, {pt, data[[All, {1, 2}]]}]]};
```

Now pull it all together like this

```
ListPlot[data[[All, 1 ;; 2]],
 PlotRange -> pRange,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{All, ticks}, {All, None}},
 Epilog -> {horzLines, vertLines}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using `ifun42` from LouisB's answer in an alternative way

```
ifun42 = Interpolation[data[[All, {4, 2}]], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
invifun42 = InverseFunction @ ifun42;

options = {BaseStyle -> Directive["TR", FontSize -> 16, Black], 
   PlotStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 1, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, Red}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{All, Charting`ScaledTicks[{ifun42, invifun42}][##, {6, 2}] &}, 
      {All, None}}, 
    GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Dashed};

ListPlot[{MapAt[ifun42, data[[All, 3 ;; 4]], {All, 2}], data[[All, 1 ;; 2]]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[15]], Black}, options]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
prolog = ListPlot[data[[All, {3, 4}]], 
    ScalingFunctions -> {None, {ifun42, invifun42}}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[15]]][[1]];

ListPlot[data[[All, 1 ;; 2]], options, Prolog -> prolog]
```

> same picture

Replace `{6, 2}` in `` Charting`ScaledTicks[...][...] `` with `{10, 1}` to get

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adapting Jason B.'s answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136419/363)

Still plots two sets of points though.

```
TwoAxisListPlot[{list1_, list2_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{plot1, plot2, ranges},
  {plot1, plot2} = ListLinePlot /@ {list1, list2};
  ranges = Last@Charting`get2DPlotRange@# & /@ {plot1, plot2};
  ranges[[2]] = Reverse@Last@ranges;
  ListPlot[{list1, Transpose[{
      First /@ list2,
      Rescale[Last /@ list2, Last@ranges, First@ranges]}]},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> {
     {Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[First@ranges, Last@ranges]},
     {Automatic, Automatic}},
   FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, ColorData[97][2]}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListPlot]]]]

data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/cJtpDmcm", "Table"];

TwoAxisListPlot[{data[[All, {1, 2}]], data[[All, {3, 4}]]}, Joined -> False]
```

[image]