# Two vertical axes in the same plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

Frequently for convenient experimental data analysis it is necessary to present results with two vertical axes in the same plot with different scale and distance between ticks.

I've tried to find solutions to this issue, but there aren't adequate ways to realize this.

1. `Overlay[{ListLogLinearPlot[...], ListLogLinearPlot[...]}]` doesn't work properly and moreover doesn't allow to use it like a template.
2. `TwoAxisPlot` is not appropriate because of need compatibility with CustomTicks package.

//CustomTicks package allows to determine accurately position of minor and major LogTicks or LinTicks.

Are there other ways to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code.

```
Show[ListLogLinearPlot[data[[3]], PlotRange -> {{10^1.3, 10^6}, {738.35, 738.65}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Orange, PointSize[0.015]}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Var_1, a.u.", "Var_2, a.u.", None, None},
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black},
  FrameStyle -> Thickness[0.001], 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Thickness[0.001],
  FrameTicks -> {{LinTicks[CMj, CMn], None}, {LogTicks, None}}], 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: You did not provide the `data`, but you should have a look at the resource function [CombinePlots](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots).

Comment: The second vertical scale can be implemented with the `FrameTicks` option.  See this [recent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229128/) and its answers for examples.

Comment: @Tim Laska, doesn't matter what data it is. Thanks for link.

Comment: You are supposed to provide minimal working example so the potential helpers do not need to divine your intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by combinning the two plots using  [CombinePlots](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots)

```
 ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"common axis", "Scale-1", None, None}], 
 Plot[ Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Red, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, 
  FrameLabel -> {"common axis", "Scale-2", None, None}], 
 "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"]
```

[image]

**Update**

Now, assume that we have a data that we want to represent with two different scales, say the scale factor is `f`, then we can still do that as follows

```
      ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][
 ListLinePlot[Table[{x, 10 x}, {x, 0, 10}], Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> Black, 
  FrameLabel -> {"common axis", "Scale-1", None, None}, 
  FrameStyle -> {Directive[{Blue, FontFamily -> "Times", 15}], 
    Directive[{Black, FontFamily -> "Times", 15}]}], 
 ListLinePlot[ Table[{x, f 10 x} /. f -> 0.1, {x, 0, 10}], 
  Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> None, 
  FrameLabel -> {"common axis", "Scale-2", None, None}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[{Red, FontFamily -> "Times", 15}]], 
 "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"]
```

here I considered that the scaling factor is `f=1/10`
[image]

Comment: In this case, the scales correspond to the plots for which they are similarly colored. What OP has asked for is not this. It would be better if you showed how to use `CombinePlots` with only one set of data, but two separate scales on the axes, as the OP has asked for—can you clarify how to do this?

Comment: @CATrevillian, thanks for the explanation, I updates my answer

Comment: This way is good. Thanks, @HD2006!