# Combining two plots on a single frame

Tags: plotting

I want to plot two plots on a single frame. First is listplot and second is plot. for example,

```
 d1 = {{100, 0.1}, {1000, 0.5}, {10000, 0.9}} 
 d2= {{100,0.5},{1000,0.7},{10000,0.89}}
  ListPlot[{d1,d2}]

 Plot[{-  0.01 Sin[0.0005 t + Pi/4],  - 0.01 Sin[
0.002 t  + Pi/4] }, {t, 0, 10000}]
```

Now the plot and listplot have same xaxis range whereas different yaxis range. I want to make frame's right yaxis for the plot and left yaxis for the listplot. How can I combine these plots on a single frame. I tried overlay but the export image size becomes huge in overlay.

Comment: Do answers at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis help?

Comment: [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229961/two-vertical-axes-in-the-same-plot/230009#230009) might help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots) with its `"AxesSides"` option:

```
d1 = {{100, 0.1}, {1000, 0.5}, {10000, 0.9}};
d2 = {{100, 0.5}, {1000, 0.7}, {10000, 0.89}};
ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][
 ListPlot[{d1, d2}, Frame -> True],
 Plot[{-0.01 Sin[0.0005 t + Pi/4], -0.01 Sin[0.002 t + Pi/4]}, {t, 0, 10000}, Frame -> True],
 "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"
 ]
```

[image]

(Note that I set `Frame->True` for both plots)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: if you have older versions, this also works : https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GeneratePlotsWithTwoVerticalScales.html