# More control over plotstyle in TwoAxisListPlot

Tags: plotting, scoping, customization

I don't understand how to modify the ColorData in the mapIndexed for the code from another post found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis) and is copied below for reference. What I want to do is control the color of each trace as well as its style (e.g., bold, dashed).

My main problem is I do not understand what "[#2[[1]]]" is doing. I understand what a slot is, but apparently not in this example. Slot one references both datasets, slot 2 gives the first two colors in the ColorData pallet chosen, and slot 3 does not exist.

If I try and force it using `PlotStyle -> {{Black,Thick},{Blue,Thick,Dashed}}` in the `MapIndexed` function it just takes the first entry for both plots. It also won't match the axes colors for reader reference.

I also tried removing `PlotStyle -> {{Black,Thick},{Blue,Thick,Dashed}}` and putting it in the options of the function calling the module the same error occurs.

Any help would be most appreciated!

````
 Module[{fgraph, ggraph, frange, grange, fticks, 
   gticks}, {fgraph, ggraph} = 
   MapIndexed[
Plot[#, {x, x1, x2}, Axes -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][#2[[1]]]] &, {f, g}]; {frange, 
grange} = (PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange])[[
  2]] & /@ {fgraph, ggraph}; fticks = N@FindDivisions[frange, 5]; 
 gticks = Quiet@
Transpose@{fticks, 
  ToString[NumberForm[#, 2], StandardForm] & /@ 
   Rescale[fticks, frange, grange]}; 
Show[fgraph, 
 ggraph /. 
Graphics[graph_, s___] :> 
 Graphics[
  GeometricTransformation[graph, 
   RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, grange}, {{0, 1}, frange}]], s], 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{fticks, gticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]]```
````

Comment: If you are on V12+ take a look at the ResourceFunction [`CombinePlots`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots).

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi that was super easy! I spent around 2.5 hours trying to figure the other code out. I still wonder what I was missing in the old code

Comment: From the previous code, this is all I had to do with my two plots formatted as I liked (p111 and p222): ```ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][p111, p222, "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"]```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would prefer to use Lukas Lang's [CombinePlots](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots) if you tried.

In case you need to play with variations on `TwoAxisPlot`, you can add an optional argument for styles and options as follows:

```
ClearAll[TwoAxisPlot2]
TwoAxisPlot2[{f_, g_}, {x_, x1_, x2_}, styles : {_, _} : (ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}), 
    o : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{fgraph, ggraph, frange, grange, fticks,  gticks}, 
 {fgraph, ggraph} = MapThread[Plot[#, {x, x1, x2}, Axes -> True, PlotStyle -> #2] &, 
     {{f, g}, styles}]; 
 {frange, grange} = (PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange])[[2]] & /@ 
     {fgraph, ggraph}; 
 fticks = N @ FindDivisions[frange, 5];
 gticks = Quiet @ Transpose@{fticks, ToString[NumberForm[#, 2], StandardForm] & /@ 
       Rescale[fticks, frange, grange]};
 Show[fgraph, ggraph /. Graphics[graph_, s___] :> 
     Graphics[GeometricTransformation[graph, 
       RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, grange}, {{0, 1}, frange}]], s], 
   Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> {styles, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{fticks, gticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, o, 
   Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Medium]]
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[{TwoAxisPlot2[{Sin[x], 10 x Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      ImageSize -> 400, LabelStyle -> 16], 
  TwoAxisPlot2[{Sin[x], 10 x Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {Red, Green}, 
      ImageSize -> 400, LabelStyle -> 16]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. That seems to work well. However, I am running V12.2 and the Combine Plots works well and is much easier to implement. I would still like to know what I was missing per my initial post. Thanks for taking the time and Happy COVID Holidays!

Comment: @ProfessorL, with `plotstyles = {{Black, Thick}, {Blue, Thick, Dashed}}` (which you can add in first argument of `Module`) you need to replace  `PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][#2[[1]]]` with `PlotStyle -> plotstyles[[#2[[1]]]]` and (if you want to use these styles for the two vertical axes)  use `FrameStyle -> {plotstyles[[#]] & /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}}`.

Comment: That worked! I still wish I knew what the ```[[#2[[1]]]]``` is doing. I am calling the index #2 in plotstyles and then calling the first position in the list from that. I suppose #2 is calling either fgraph or ggraph. I am still struggling with why #2 calls these when it is inside the MapIndexed.

Comment: @ProfessorL, the examples `MapIndexed[foo[#, #2] &, {a, b, c}]` and `MapIndexed[{bar[#], buz[#2]} &, {a, b, c}]`  and `MapIndexed[{bar[#], {x, y, z, w}[[#2[[1]]]]} &, {a, b, c}]`  might help re how the slots `#` and `#2` work in the first argument of `MapIndexed`.