# Generate Plots with Two Vertical Scales

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I was trying to generate a plot with two different y axis, i found a post in the wolfram forum about this topic it's called the TwoAxisPlot but it doesn't work like it's described, here's the code from the wolfram page

```
TwoAxisPlot[{f_, g_}, {x_, x1_, x2_}] := 
 Module[{fgraph, ggraph, frange, grange, fticks, 
   gticks}, {fgraph, ggraph} = 
   MapIndexed[
    Plot[#, {x, x1, x2}, Axes -> True, 
      PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][#2[[1]]]] &, {f, g}]; {frange, 
    grange} = (PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange])[[
      2]] & /@ {fgraph, ggraph}; fticks = N@FindDivisions[frange, 5]; 
  gticks = Quiet@
    Transpose@{fticks, 
      ToString[NumberForm[#, 2], StandardForm] & /@ 
       Rescale[fticks, frange, grange]}; 
  Show[fgraph, 
   ggraph /. 
    Graphics[graph_, s___] :> 
     Graphics[
      GeometricTransformation[graph, 
       RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, grange}, {{0, 1}, frange}]], s], 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{fticks, gticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]]
```

this is the example that they give to you

```
TwoAxisPlot[{Sin[x], 3 Sin[x] + 5 Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

this is my code and what i tried

```
sol = NDSolve[{Ca'[t] == 
    25 - 0.005 Ca[t] - 8 10^12 E^(-22500/(1.987 T[t] )) Ca[t], 
   T'[t] == 
    0.005 (300 - T[t]) + 
     0.01 (8 10^12 E^(-22500/(1.987 T[t] ))) Ca[t] - 
     0.001 (T[t] - 330), Ca[0] == 5000, T[0] == 330}, {Ca, T}, {t, 
   1500}]
Plot[{Ca[t], T[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> All]
TwoAxisPlot[{f_, g_}, {x_, x1_, x2_}] := 
 Module[{fgraph, ggraph, frange, grange, fticks, 
   gticks}, {fgraph, ggraph} = 
   MapIndexed[
    Plot[#, {x, x1, x2}, Axes -> True, 
      PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][#2[[1]]]] &, {f, g}]; {frange, 
    grange} = (PlotRange /. 
        AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange])[[2]] & /@ {fgraph, ggraph}; 
  fticks = N@FindDivisions[frange, 5];
  gticks = 
   Quiet@Transpose@{fticks, 
      ToString[NumberForm[#, 2], StandardForm] & /@ 
       Rescale[fticks, frange, grange]};
  Show[fgraph, 
   ggraph /. 
    Graphics[graph_, s___] :> 
     Graphics[
      GeometricTransformation[graph, 
       RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, grange}, {{0, 1}, frange}]], s], 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{fticks, gticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]]

TwoAxisPlot[{Ca[t], T[t]}, {t, 0, 1000}]
```

this is the example

[image]

this is how my plot should be

[image]

any idea on how to manipulate the code from the wolfram page to make it work with these functions? here's the link to the article https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GeneratePlotsWithTwoVerticalScales.html

thanks a lot, any help would be kindly and hugely appreciated

Comment: Does `TwoAxisPlot[{Ca[t], T[t]} /. Flatten@sol, {t, 0, 1000}]` give the expected result?

Comment: You may also be interested in [1 plot / 2 scale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis) and [CombinePlots](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots/).

Comment: It does, thanks @LouisB