# Plot MOSFET Simultaneous equations

Tags: plotting

**Hello guys,**

I'm trying to plot the following two simultaneous equations within the same plot:

```
eq1: IDS1 :==: KN * (VGS - VTH - VDS/2)*VDS ;
eq2: IDS1 :==: (VDD - VDS)/RD;
```

The thing is: I already have the corresponding Values for VDS and IDS as you can see it below on my code, what I just want to do is plot them, I've been working in Mathematica for a while but only with symbolic calculus.

I've solved this problem analytically, but I want to add the graph as well, and include it on the final notebook.

Unfortunately I don't get it how to properly plot the solution(I've been trying in so ways without any luck).
Also, I've solve it on Matlab, but I don't get it out how to do it on Mathematica, and I really want to do it with Mathematica.

I hope you could help me.
BTW: Here's how I do It with Matlab(the graph) and my Actual Notebook on Mathematica:
[image: Actual Code]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
VDD = 10;
VTH = 4;
VGS = 5;
KN   = 1.173;
RD   = 100;
VDS = Range[0, 6, 0.01];(*Equivalent to var=[0:0.001:2] in matlab*)

IDS1 = KN * (VGS - VTH - VDS/2)*VDS ;
IDS2 = (VDD - VDS)/RD;

Plot[{{IDS1}, {IDS2}}, {VDS, 0, 10}, 
AxesLabel -> {"VDS(V)", "IDS(mA)"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]

ClearAll["Global`*"]
VDD = 10;
VTH = 4;
VGS = 5;
KN   = 1.173;
RD   = 100;

eq1 = KN * (VGS - VTH - VDS/2)*VDS - IDS1 == 0;(*Used only when transistor is used as     
switch: I.O.:Q Working in Triode/Ohmic Region *)

eq2 = (VDD - VDS)/RD - IDS1 == 0; (*Comes from applying KVL to Drain-Source Loop*)
N[EngineeringForm[Solve[{ eq1, eq2}, {VDS, IDS1}]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amplifying on answer by Jagra

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

VDD = 10;
VTH = 4;
VGS = 5;
KN = 1.173;
RD = 100;
VDS = Range[0, 6, 0.01];

IDS1 = KN*(VGS - VTH - VDS/2)*VDS;

IDS2 = (VDD - VDS)/RD;
```

`IDS1` and `IDS2` are lists, not functions. Use [`ListLinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) rather than [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html). Also, since their scales are radically different use [`ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots/)

```
ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][
 ListLinePlot[IDS1,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> ColorData[97][1],
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1],
  DataRange -> {0, 6}],
 ListLinePlot[IDS2,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> ColorData[97][2],
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][2],
  DataRange -> {0, 6}],
 "AxesSides" -> "TwoY",
 FrameLabel -> {{"IDS1(mA)", "IDS2(mA)"}, {Style["VDS(V)", Black], None}}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
Clear[VDS, IDS1]

KN = 1.173 // Rationalize;

eq1 = KN*(VGS - VTH - VDS/2)*VDS - IDS1 == 0;

eq2 = (VDD - VDS)/RD - IDS1 == 0;

(sol = Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {VDS, IDS1}]) // N // 
 EngineeringForm[#, {6, 2}] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bob Hanlon for answering, unfortunately, I don't have the latest version of Mathematica, the one I'm using it's quite old, but I've spinned out your code, in order to use it with the version I have, and here's the results:

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx84W.png)

Comment: For older versions look at older Q&A on this site, e.g., [`link`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/627/9362)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made things more complicated than you need to.

Does the following give you something closer to what you want?

```
VDD = 10;
VTH = 4;
VGS = 5;
KN = 1.173;
RD = 100;
VDS = Range[0, 6, 0.01];
IDS1 = KN*(VGS - VTH - VDS/2)*VDS;
IDS2 = (VDD - VDS)/RD;

ListLinePlot[{IDS1, IDS2}, AxesLabel -> {"VDS(V)", "IDS(mA)"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1/3, ImageSize->400]
```

[image]

You've already created two lists of the data you need to display.
`ListLinePlot` gives you what you need.

---

I haven't had a chance to study your second bit of code:

```
VDD = 10;
VTH = 4;
VGS = 5;
KN   = 1.173;
RD   = 100;

eq1 = KN * (VGS - VTH - VDS/2)*VDS - IDS1 == 0;
(*Used only when transistor is used as switch: I.O.:Q Working in Triode/Ohmic Region *)

eq2 = (VDD - VDS)/RD - IDS1 == 0; 
(*Comes from applying KVL to Drain-Source Loop*)

N[EngineeringForm[Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {VDS, IDS1}]]]
```

Review `Solve` in the documentation.  On first look your's doesn't look set up right.

I'll come back to this later, but I suspect you'll get an answer or two in the meantime.

Comment: Very well @Jagra and Thanks.